# How can I change the volume name of a FAT32 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, partition, fat

How can I change the volume name of a FAT32 filesystem? 
I know I can set the volume name when I format the partition
with the `-n` option of `mkfs.vfat`. 
But how to just change the name without formatting?

I especially want to be able to use lower and uppercase letters. 
In worst case, I can use a Windows tool, but Windows by default transforms all letters to uppercase (but works fine with lowercase letters in volumes created with `mkfs.vfat`).

Comment: Related on [SU]: [How to change the filesystem label on the vfat filesystem located on device /dev/sdb1?](http://superuser.com/q/179864/269404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the only way I found to change a FAT volume name
with lower case letters is to edit it with a hex editor
(copy the first few sectors with `dd` to a temporary file,
edit it and copy it back). 
It works well so far (even with FAT16)
and neither `fsck` nor CHKDSK from Windows 7 complained. 
But no guarantee, of course ;-)

Answer (score 84):

[Dosfstools](https://github.com/dosfstools/dosfstools), which provides `mkfs.vfat` and friends, also provides `fatlabel` (called `dosfslabel` in older versions) to change the label.

Comment: I will try this in some days. Do you know if it can save lower-case letters?

Comment: It didn't work whit lower case letters. And after use, I got errors on the file system....

Comment: dosfslabel changed from supporting lower-case labels
as of version 3.0.12 to rejecting them in 3.0.16

Comment: @DMcKeon: it seems to work in 3.0.27, with a warning.

Comment: blivet (at least, blivet3-data-3.1.3-3.el7) rejects lower-case labels for EFI partitions.  dosfslabel (aka fatlabel, from dosfstools-3.0.20-10.el7) accepts them with a warning.  So, blivet's being preemptively annoying.

Answer (score 44):

For my USB drive `mlabel` did not work, but `fatlabel`worked!

```
fatlabel /dev/device
```

gives you label

```
fatlabel /dev/device NEW_LABEL
```

sets new label

Comment: Because we label a file system and usually it is on a partition here is my command: `sudo fatlabel /dev/sdXN NewLabel` (**/dev/sdf1**, for example)

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use mkdosfs (mkfs.vfat) : it lets the user specify the volume label using the -n flag, and lowercase letters are kept lowercase, but this tool recreates the filesystem, so all data will be lost.

The non-destructive solution below is a combination of the mlabel and dosfslabel command-line tools.

> 1. Connect the device to the computer if not already connected.
> 2. Open a terminal window.
> 3. Run `blkid | grep ' TYPE="vfat"' and </proc/mounts grep ' vfat '` to figure out the name of the device (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`). Look around
>      in /media etc. to confirm you have picked the right device. If unsure,
>      unplug it, run the commands again, see it disappear, plug it back, and
>      run the commands again.
> 4. Unmount the device by running `umount /dev/sdb1` (substituting `/dev/sdb1` with the name of the device found above). If it was mounted,
>      and the unmount failed, then close some windows, kill some programs
>      (e.g. `fuser -m /dev/sdb1`), and try unmounting again.
> 5. Run `sudo env MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 ::x` (substituting /dev/sdb1 with the name of the device found above). If
>      the system can't find mlabel, then install it by running sudo apt-get
>      install mtools , and try again.
> 6. Run `sudo dosfslabel /dev/sdb1 MyLabel` (substituting MyLabel with the desired label and `/dev/sdb1` with the name of the device found
>      above). Ignore any warnings about boot sector differences. If the
>      system can't find dosfslabel, then install it by running sudo apt-get
>      install dosfstools , and try again.
> 7. Run `blkid | grep ' TYPE="vfat"'`, and examine its output to verify that the label has been changed properly. Optionally, unplug
>      the device, and then plug it back in. The system will recognize it,
>      and mount it under /media/MyLabel, without converting lowercase
>      letters in the volume label to uppercase.

Please note that there is an 11 character limit on the length of a VFAT volume label. If you specify a longer label, it will be truncated. There is another restriction: the label can contain only (some) ASCII characters: accented letters etc. won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer! Can you explain what the command in 5. is doing exactly? It sets the label to 'x'?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Ubuntu page about renaming USB drives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive#FAT16_and_FAT32). 
It's basically:

```
mlabel -i <device> ::<label>
```

Comment: Thanks! Change the name works, but it is transvormed to upercase:
# mlabel -i /dev/sdc1 ::redsd
# mlabel -i /dev/sdc1 -s ::
 Volume label is REDSD

Comment: @Den FAT disk labels are uppercase only

Comment: @Matteo I have here a HD whit FAT32 which have lower and upper case letters in the name: mlabel -vi /dev/sdb1 -s ::
 Volume label is miniTR

Comment: @Den yes FAT32 supports it. It is most likely a FAT16 formatted drive.

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for confirming I'm not completely silly ;-) The device I try to rename is a 15.9 GB FAT32 formated SD card.

Answer (score 2):

The above commands didn't worked for me on Rasberry Pi / Rasbian Jessie 8.
I decided to go with `gparted`.

Go to the Menu: *Partition / Label*. Write your desired name and then click on the green pipe (apply).

After the procedure you can see the details hided under the "multiple" + sign.
There is a command total other:

```
 mlabel ::"LABEL_NAME" -i/dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a GUI alternative, `gparted` has a `Label File System` menu item for many file systems, including VFAT. It becomes available after unmounting the file system.

Answer (score 0):

An update :
Since now, the FAT32 file system has been superseded by the new exFAT for most flash devices, you my find that fatlabel do not work on many cards. you should the try exfatlabel instead of fatlabel

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for coming back to this 7 years later, but this is a top answer on google for the question, and I didn't have any of the tools suggested in the existing answers on the system I was using.

As a last resort,

```
if [ "`dd if=/dev/hda1 bs=1 count=7 skip=54 2>/dev/null`" = 'FAT16  ' ] ; then
  echo -n 'MYNEWLABEL1' | dd of=/dev/hda1 seek=43 count=11 bs=1 conv=notrunc
elif [ "`dd if=/dev/hda1 bs=1 count=7 skip=82 2>/dev/null`" = 'FAT32  ' ] ; then
  echo -n 'MYNEWLABEL1' | dd of=/dev/hda1 seek=71 count=11 bs=1 conv=notrunc
fi
```

ought to work.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. May I recommend that you use the `$( ... )` style for command substitutions insted of the backticks, as these are [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) now.

Comment: This is an unwise last resort.  It makes assumptions about the BPB and the rest of the volume that aren't necessarily, or even usually, true.  For example, often the volume label is entries in the root directory.  If you don't have the tools, the right thing to do is *obtain them*.  `fatlabel` handles the various BPB and root directory possibilties

Comment: JdeBP: "even usually" "often". I'd dispute both.

I've personally never come across a volume label in the root directory, and the "assumptions" it makes about the BPB are defined. Finally, if it turns out the assumptions are incorrect and you do have some bizarrely formatted disk that doesn't conform to the standard, it should be non-destructive. I would say in the majority case this will be sufficient.

And telling someone to obtain tools, which may take hours of faffing with build environments just to label a disk is facile. If you have the tools, sure use them. If not, this should work.

Comment: Then you do not heave nearly enough experience with FAT.  The volume label being directory entries has long been commonplace.  This is not ¨bizarre" nor is it non-standard.  Whereas in contrast this solution is unwise and has no guarantee of working at all, not least because the volume label in the root directory often gets precedence.

Comment: I wrote my first FAT disk parser for an 8-bit home micro 28 years ago. If you dislike the solution, why not modify it to include the things you believe it needs rather than just whining about how it wouldn't work (when it demonstrably does)?