# Error when calling a script from inside another script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing a couple of scripts to start `vlc` and periodically update its playlist.
The `update_pls.sh` works well if I execute it from prompt, but when I call it from `start_vlc.sh`, in each `for` cycle I get this:

```bash
./update_pls.sh: 20: ./update_pls.sh: 10#18: not found
./update_pls.sh: 20: ./update_pls.sh: 10#18==DIA: not found
```

**start_vlc.sh:**

```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   echo `date`
   echo "A arrancar o VLC..."
   cvlc --loop --fullscreen --extraintfttp --http-password kepler
   sh update_pls.sh
```

**update_pls.sh:**

```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/env > /Videos/cron_env.log
   DIR=/Videos
   FILES=$DIR/*
   DIA=`(date +%d)`
   HORA=`(date +%H)`
   echo `date`
   echo "Dir: $DIR"
   echo "A fazer update da playlist.m3u..."
   > $DIR/playlist.m3u
   for f in $FILES
   do
     a=`(basename $f .mov | cut -b 1-2 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')`
     b=`(basename $f .mov | cut -b 3-4 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')`
     if [ -n "$a" ]; then    
       :
     else
       a="99"
     fi
     if (( 10#$a<DIA)) || ((10#$a==DIA && 10#$b<=HORA )); then
       echo -e "$f\n" >> $DIR/playlist.m3u
       echo "Adicionado o video $f"
     fi
   done
   echo "A fazer upload da playlist para o VLC..."
   curl -u '':kepler "http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_empty"
   curl -u '':kepler "http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml?command=in_enqueue&input$
   curl -u '':kepler "http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_play"
```

I can't manage to find the cause of this and would apreciate any help.
Vasco

Comment: When you are calling the script, can you put in the directory the script is located in? For example `.~/directory/scriptName.sh`

Comment: both scripts, and files it's supposed to add to the playlist, are in the same folder, p.e. /home/vasco/videos/.

Comment: Ok next dumb question lol: is the script listed as an executable?

Comment: @VascoSotomaior in UNIX world, you have to specify path for executing script or run from `$PATH`.

Comment: yup, after writing them i ran `sudo chmod +x *.sh`

Comment: @VascoSotomaior, I would take Mohsen's word for it, as I first suspected, it was because the whole directory path wasn't listed but I wasn't 100% on that one.

Comment: @VascoSotomaior Check your script in [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) - You've got some errors in there.

Comment: `vlc` comes with a fully-scriptable cli. Do `vlc -I lua` then type `help` and play around.

Answer (score 2):

Your `update_pls.sh` is a `bash` script, but when you invoke it from `start_vlc.sh` you use `sh` which probably doesn't run `bash` on your system. Try either changing the line to `bash update_pls.sh` or do `chmod a+x` on `update_pls.sh` and just invoke it directly as a command.

A few notes on your scripts:

In the line `` echo `date` ``, `echo` is unnecessary, just use `date`.

No need for parenthesis in lines like `` DIA=`(date +%d)` ``, including these will start another instance of your shell and add a lot of overhead to the script. `DIA=$(date)` is probably the most preferable form (here the dollar brackets replace the backticks), see [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated).

No need for a `:` in your if/else, just do `if ! [ -n "$a" ]; then` and you can drop the else part.

There are some other things, but I think that is enough from me.

Comment: @mikeserv On my Debian system `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash`.

Comment: @Dubu - thats true. Id forgotten that. `dash` is a better shell than `bash`'s --posix mode anyway, as it too often confuses itself, i think. And it will be that way on all Debian based systems - which completely invalidates my comment. Sorry, Graeme. In all, though, i would recommend `vlc -I lua` - which invokes `vlc`'s own scriptable cli - over all of this.