# Leaving VIFM in such a way that the terminal directory is the same as the last visited VIFM directory

Tags: vifm

I'm trying to achieve what was described in the title.  I followed these directions (http://sourceforge.net/p/vifm/feature-requests/24/) but they did not work.  Here are the instructions I followed:

> 1. Add special command to vifmrc command Q :execute '!echo %d > ~/.vifm/lastdir' | quit
> 2. Add an alias to .bashrc alias vifm='source ~/bin/vf'
> 3. Save the following script to ~/bin/vf if [ -f ~/.vifm/lastdir ]; then rm ~/.vifm/lastdir fi /usr/local/bin/vifm "$@" if [ -f
>      ~/.vifm/lastdir ]; then cd cat ~/.vifm/lastdir fi

I'm most skeptical of (3).  I had to create a "bin" folder in my home directory, and then create a "vf" file within the new "bin" to then place the text described in (3).  Did I proceed correctly here?

Comment: Is `~/bin` in your $PATH? Is `~/bin/vf` executable? Is `vifm` installed at `/usr/local/bin/`? Personally, I am sceptical about (3) as well...

Comment: I'm a linux newbie and don't know off hand how to verify these things.

Comment: Except I can verify that that vifm is indeed installed in /usr/local/bin/

Comment: `echo $PATH` will tell you whether `~/bin` is included. `cd ~/bin && ls -la` will show an `-x` at the end of the string for executable for that script.

Comment: check if /usr/local/bin/vifm is really work. If not type "which vifm" for exact location. Indentation is also imprtant as in the below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a reformat of the desired script would be helpful here. It should look exactly like the following:

#### ~/bin/vf

```
if [ -f ~/.vifm/lastdir ]; then
    rm ~/.vifm/lastdir
fi
/usr/local/bin/vifm "$@"
if [ -f ~/.vifm/lastdir ]; then
    cd "`cat ~/.vifm/lastdir`"
fi
```

Note in particular the reverse tick marks around the `cat` command on the second-to-last line, those seem to have gone missing from your version and are rather important. I've also added extra `"` around the argument to `cd` in case your current directory has spaces.

This is really a terrible hack to make your program look like it's doing something that programs can't normally do. But, if it helps you get work done, great.

Comment: This works great (!) except in cases where there are spaces in one of the folder names.

Comment: Spaces? You must be new to Linux indeed. :) To fix that, use more quotes. I've updated my answer to add some `"`.

Comment: Or just use `cd "$(cat ~/.vifm/lastdir)"` so you don't need to use backticks.  See [Have backticks (i.e. `\`cmd\``) in \*sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/135943)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need just to go to terminal?
Just do this in vifm

```
:sh
```

If you need to aganing enter to vifm you need just make this

```
exit <OR> ctrl-D
```

but you enter in vifm in same dir that you entered to this terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory you want in vifm. And enter `:e`. Then you might want to use `:terminal`.