# grep a awk string from a file and write to the other part of string file

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

My file, aaa,has 5 lines.

```
01_AAA-11-ID22
02_BBB-33-ID44
03_CCC-55-ID66
.
.
```

I tried to grep anything after underline from a file bigfile.txt

```
for i in $(cat aaa)
do
A= $(awk -F '_' '{print $1}' $i)
B= $(awk -F '_' '{print $2}' $i)
grep $B bigfile.txt > $A
done
```

I tried to do

```
grep AAA-11-22 bigfile.txt > 01
```

But, it seems not working. My error code is

awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `01_AAA-11-22' for reading (No such file or directory)

Need some advise. Thanks,

Comment: can you provide sample input file and sample expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo `$i` instead of trying to open it as a file:

```
for i in $(cat aaa)
do
  A= $(echo $1 | awk -F '_' '{print $1}')
  B= $(echo $i | awk -F '_' '{print $2}')
  grep $B bigfile.txt > $A
done
```

However, if you are interested, you could replace this for-loop entirely with an `awk` one-liner:

```
awk -F '_' '{system("grep "$2" bigfile.txt > "$1)}' aaa
```

Comment: I tried the one-liner but it does not work. But, the first one works good. Thanks.

Comment: I've tested the one-liner myself, probably it happened due to different `awk` versions (I'm using `mawk`). I'm glad the answer helped you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use **awk** at all

```
while read i
do
    grep ${i#*_} bigfile.txt > ${i%%_*}
done <aaa
```

For **GNU sed**

```
sed 's/\([^_]\+\)_\(.*\)/sed "\/\2\/!d" bigfile.txt >"\1"/e' aaa
```

For **awk** (if you'd like)

```
awk -F_ '
    NR == FNR{
        A[$2] = $1
        next
    }
    {
        for(a in A)
            if($0 ~ a)
                print > A[a]
    }
    ' aaa bigfile.txt
```

For big files you will have to use

```
                print >> A[a]
                close(A[a])
```

Comment: I really liked your trick to process the two files separately but in the same script.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `echo` to pass the `$i` to awk. Otherwise it looks for a file.

```
A=$(echo $i | awk -F_ '{print $1}')
```

Same with B

Comment: The ` notation is deprecated, use `$()` instead.

Comment: Did not know that...edited my answer

Comment: Deprecated is not the best word for it, is is just not advisable to use it, check this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) if you are interested.