# How to execute a script located in the same directory as the current script?

Tags: shell-script

Why are shell scripts are so hard to develop? In NodeJS I could simply do:

```
require('./script')
```

and it will always require `script` relative to the current script. But if I try that in shell/bash:

```
./script.sh
```

it will look for script relative to `cwd` (`pwd`). Seems the dot means `cwd` (`pwd`) and not the directory where current script is located as I was expecting.

```
line 8: ./script.sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I execute a script relative to the directory where the current executing script is located?

I have tried

```
/bin/bash script.sh
```

but I get the error:

```
/bin/bash: script.sh: No such file or directory
```

Then I tried

```
script.sh
```

Got this error

```
line 8: script.sh: command not found
```

Only the following solution worked fine, but the problem is that it is unreadable:

```
$("$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")/script.sh")
```

Answer (score 16):

Another variant to get script dir:

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
```

then you can call script with

```
$DIR/script.sh
```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately that is the way to go.

Another way (which I prefer) is to cd into the current dir at the beginning of your scripts like this:

```
cd $(dirname $0)
```

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have indicated, your solution is correct.

- As the other answers have suggested,
  you can get the script directory once and use it multiple times. 
  This may be cleaner and more efficient.
- As the other answers have suggested, you might not need the `realpath`. 
  Can you say why you believe that you need it?
- You seem to have an extra `$(` and `)` in your solution.

  ```
  "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")/script.sh"
  ```

  should be enough …
- … except there’s a really subtle corner case that nobody else pointed out. 
  Let’s homogenize the other answers:

  ```
  DIR="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
  "$DIR"/script.sh
  ```

  If the “current script” is in the root directory
  (e.g., it is `/first_script`),
  and assuming that `realpath` doesn’t have any effect,
  we will get `DIR="/"`, so the

  ```
  "$DIR"/script.sh
  ```

  line will be expanded as

  ```
  "/"/script.sh
  ```

  i.e.,

  ```
  //script.sh
  ```

  This is typically equivalent to `/script.sh`. 
  But Unix (POSIX) reserves the right to treat `//`
  *at the beginning* of a pathname specially. 
  It is infinitesimally safer to do

  ```
  DIR="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"/
  "$DIR"/script.sh
  ```

  with an (extra, explicit) `/` at the end of the definition of `DIR`. 
  If `$0` is `/first_script`, `DIR` will be set to `//`,
  and `"$DIR"/script.sh` will be expanded as `///script.sh`,
  which is *guaranteed* to be equivalent to `/script.sh`. 
  And if `$0` is something more common, like `/foo/bin/first_script`,
  then `DIR` will be set to `/foo/bin/`,
  and `"$DIR"/script.sh` will be expanded as `/foo/bin//script.sh`,
  which is also *guaranteed* to be equivalent to `/foo/bin/script.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

In ***most cases***, when `script.sh` is in the same directory, you can use just:

```
${0%/*}/script.sh
```

*Explanation:*
`$0` stores the name of your process (in ***most cases*** it's the full path to your script).
`${parameter%word}` removes suffix pattern `word` from variable `$parameter` (in the command above it removes file name `/*` from the full path stored in variable `$0`).

If for ***some reasons*** you don't want to use `$0`, in **bash** you can use `$BASH_SOURCE` instead:

```
${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/helper.sh
```

As for me, these are the easiest ways to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on the Answer from [Mikael Kjær](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295807/546201).

I had problems handling path with spaces in them but was able to solve it using

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$0` refers to your current script and `dirname $0` will get the directory name of your current script (the full path without the file name)

so you can do it like this:

```
$(dirname $0)/script.sh
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you  for your contribution. Please note that the "backtick"-style for command substitutions is [discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) and the new `$( ... )`-style is now recommended.

Comment: (1) This is a subset of the answer *that was presented **in the question**!* Do you claim that `realpath` is totally unnecessary in this situation? Can you justify such a claim?  (2) You should learn why people use quotes.