# Do functions run as subprocesses in Bash?

Tags: bash, process, function

In [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), in [example 27-4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html#ARRAYSTROPS), 7-th line from the bottom, I've read this:

> A function runs as a sub-process.

I did a test in Bash, and it seems that the above statement is wrong.

Searches on this site, Bash Man, and my search engine don't bring any light.

Do you have the answer and would like to explain?

Comment: As noted, that guide is misleading in the extreme.  I recommend the [Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) instead.

Comment: An important fact is that "Bash" avoids to create subshells. They are expensive, has your own environment, and those affect performance of the script as well the way how the code flows (many times, inconveniently, in order to deal with their particularities). The actual state of Bash is a product of a evolution, a code evolution. I mean, the first version of Bash uses more subshells*** than the actual one. This kind of inconsistency seems to be reasonable.

***if you want a proof, I can't give you. I've derived it from webpages, comments... I've read that statement somewhere sometime ago.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide is not always reliable and its example scripts contain out-dated practices such as using the [effectively deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated#link-post-126928) backticks for command substitution, i.e., `` `command` `` rather than `$(command)`.

In this particular case, it’s blatantly incorrect.

The section on [Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) in the (canonical) Bash manual definitively states that

> Shell functions are executed in the current shell context; no new process is created to interpret them.

Comment: _"Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide is generally unreliable"_  Very true.

Comment: Can you give references to support your first sentence?

Comment: @WillVousden what would a reference look like here? A bunch of examples of the guide's technical shortfalls? A document where experts in the bash community have previously noted that it is unreliable? Would it help if a stackoverflow member with a gold badge in bash just agreed in a comment? :p

Comment: @kojiro An overview of its problems and/or a more comprehensive list of examples would be good.  Currently, the advice for Bash novices is that "it's bad, m'kay?"

Comment: @WillVousden I don't think what you want exists in a reliable form itself. Mendel Cooper has updated and fixed issues with the guide in the past, but there is no public bug tracker or list of errata. (Perhaps that is the most damning statement I can make.) So when we find a flaw (perceived or real) all we can do is email the author and hope for the best.

Comment: @WillVousden, ...if you want a *history* of how long the consensus in the freenode #bash channel has been that the ABS should be avoided, see http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs -- the second field in each line is the timestamp, and the first is the username; I'm going to hope that assertion that the usernames in question are very well-respected individuals suffices.

Comment: @WillVousden I wrote this answer quickly (before going to bed). I've since toned down the criticism of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide in the first sentence as my original wording was overly harsh and unjustified.

Comment: "An overview of its problems and/or a more comprehensive list of examples would be good." -- ridiculous request.

Answer (score 44):

Curly brace functions will run within the calling shell process, unless they  need their own  subshell which is:

- when you run them in the background with `&`
- when you run them as a link in a pipeline

Redirections or extra env. variables won't force a new subshell:

```
hw(){
    echo hello world from $BASHPID
    echo var=$var
} 
var=42 hw >&2
echo $BASHPID  #unexports var=42 and restores stdout here
```

If you define the function  with parentheses instead of curlies:

```
hw()(
  echo hello world from $BASHPID
)
hw 
echo $BASHPID
```

it will always run in a new process.

Command substitution `$()` also always creates processes in bash (but not in ksh if you run builtins inside it).

Comment: I didn't know `f() (...)` is allowed. Are there any other definitions apart from `{...}` and `(...)`? In Bash, I'm not into others yet.

Comment: @tomas You can use the `function hw { echo hello world; }`  syntax (no need for `()` if you type out `function` and you can specify redirections right after the final `}` or `)` as in `hw(){ echo error; } >&2`. That's about it.

Comment: I knew these. Tx.

Comment: This is the answer I immediately thought about, and it is absolutely correct. It should be voted as the correct answer. `f()(...)` always execute an own shell, whilst `f(){...}` does not.

Comment: NB bash functions accept any compound command, so `foo() [[ x = x ]]` is a valid function definition, too. However, if you look at the function with `type foo` you'll see that this is still syntactic sugar for `foo() { [[ x = x ]]; }`. The same is true of subshell functions: `bar() ( : )` becomes `bar() { ( : ); }`.

Comment: @kojiro nice +1. didn't know that

Answer (score 10):

The command in question from that example looks like:

```
echo ${arrayZ[@]/%e/$(replacement)}
```

The example later states:

```
#    $( ... ) is command substitution.
#    A function runs as a sub-process.
```

Being charitable to ABS Guide, what they apparently meant to write is that the function runs inside a *command substitution* and the command inside a command substitution runs in a *subshell*.

Comment: That's very misleading. Thanks for your interpretation.

Comment: @tomas _"very misleading."_  Yes, very.  In contrast to the ABS Guide, [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) is an excellent source of advanced bash information.

Comment: Cheers. What's your opinion about this one: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/start ?

Comment: @tomas  I have no first hand knowledge of that one.

Comment: @tomas, ...my own opinion as to the bash-hackers wiki is that it's an excellent source. I haven't been through it as comprehensively as I have the Wooledge wiki, but it tends to be accurate and precisely written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I know your skills from SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd note, that if executed in the *background*, a bash function will execute in a subshell.  I only note this because I stumbled onto this question while checking for that fact.

```
[192.168.28.1 (1ae7468c) ~ 19:17:50]# function foo () { echo $BASHPID; }
[192.168.28.1 (1ae7468c) ~ 19:17:59]# foo
807477
[192.168.28.1 (1ae7468c) ~ 19:18:02]# foo
807477
[192.168.28.1 (1ae7468c) ~ 19:18:03]# foo &
[1] 1996783
1996783
[1]+  Done                    foo
[192.168.28.1 (1ae7468c) ~ 19:18:06]#
```