# continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop

Tags: function, for, subshell

I have a loop that checks for certain criteria for whether or not to skip to the next iteration (A). I realized that if I invoke a function (`skip`) that calls `continue`, it is as if it is called in a sub-process for it does not see the loop (B). Also the proposed workaround that relies on `eval`-uating a string does not work (C).

```
# /usr/bin/bash env

skip()
{
    echo "skipping : $1"
    continue   
}

skip_str="echo \"skipping : $var\"; continue"

while read -r var;
do
    if [[ $var =~  ^bar$  ]];
    then
        # A
        #        echo "skipping : $var"
        #        continue
        # B
        #        skip "$var" #  continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
        # C
        eval "$skip_str"
    fi
    echo "processed: $var"
done < <(cat << EOF 
foo
bar
qux
EOF
        )
```

Method C:

```
$ source ./job-10.sh
processed: foo
skipping : 
processed: qux
```

Also see:

[Do functions run as subprocesses in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305358/do-functions-run-as-subprocesses-in-bash)

PS1: could someone remind me why `< <` rather than `<` is needed after `done`?

PS2: no tag found for `while` hence `for`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Note that your shebang is wrong (it won't affect the script). You want _either_ `/usr/bin/env bash` _or_ `/bin/bash` but not `/usr/bin/bash env`.

Comment: When you define `skip_str` you end up evaluating `$var` there and then, so when you call `eval` there's no variable to evaluate. But this is really poor practice anyway so don't do it like this

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to do, I would imagine you'll get some better quality code in an answer

Comment: The syntax `<( command )` runs `command`, stores the stdout in a tmp file, and substitutes itself with the tmp filename. The preceding `<` is a normal redirect that attaches that tmp filename to stdin of the `while do done`, and is inherited by all of its child processes (in this case the `read` built-in).

Comment: @terdon: And the shebang is missing the bang, too.

Comment: @userunknown whoops, so it is, thanks. And thanks for fixing it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when your function is executed, it is no longer inside a loop. It isn't in a subshell, no, but it is also not inside any loop. As far as the function is concerned, it is a self-contained piece of code and has no knowledge of where it was called from.

Then, when you run `eval "$skip_str"` there is no value in `$var` because you have set `skip_string` at a time when `$var` was not defined. This should actually work as you expect, it's just seriously convoluted and risky (if you don't control input 100%) for no reason:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

while read -r var;
do
  skip_str="echo \"skipping : $var\"; continue"
  if [[ $var =~  ^bar$  ]];
  then
    eval "$skip_str"
  fi
  echo "processed: $var"

done < <(cat << EOF 
foo
bar
qux
EOF
        )
```

That... really isn't very pretty. Personally, I would just use a function to do the test and then operate on the test's results. Like this:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

doTest(){
  if [[ $1 =~  ^bar$  ]];
  then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
  
}

while read -r var;
do
  if doTest "$var"; then
    echo "processed: $var"
  else
    echo "skipped: $var"
    continue
  fi

## Rest of your code here

done < <(cat << EOF 
foo
bar
qux
EOF
        )
```

I could probably give you something better if you explained what your objective is.

Finally, you don't need `< <` after `done`, you need `< <()`. The `<` is the normal input redirection, and the `<()` is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and is a trick that lets you treat the output of a command as though it were a file name.

If you are using the function just to avoid repeating the extra things like `echo "skipping $1"`, you could simply move more of the logic into the function so that you have a loop there. Something like this: [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: @roaima oh, sure. Various things could be improved, but I wanted to keep it explicit so the OP can easily grok the logic.

Comment: That function could be collapsed to `doTest() { [[ ! $1 =~  ^bar$  ]]; }`

Comment: @roaima, and if we were to golf it, `doTest() [[ ! $1 =~ ^bar$  ]];` also works ;)

Comment: @ilkkachu or `doTest(){ [ $1 != bar ];}` which plays both golf _and_ portability :P

Comment: @terdon, but then you need to quote! But no, golfing isn't important, so I'll stop now...

Comment: Believe it or not I wasn't trying to golf. Really!

Answer (score 4):

The function runs in the same process all right, it's just syntactically distinct from the loop. In pretty much any other programming language, you also can't use `break` or `continue` inside a function to affect a loop outside it.

But actually, in the shell, [it's unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#continue):

> `continue [n]`
> If *n* is specified, the continue utility shall return to the top of the *n*th enclosing for, while, or until loop. If *n* is not specified, continue shall behave as if *n* was specified as 1. [...]
>
> [...] **If there is no enclosing loop, the behavior is unspecified.**

What you get depends on the shell:

Bash gives you the error and ignores the `continue`:

```
$ bash -c 'f() { continue; }; for x in a b c; do f; echo $x; done; echo done'
environment: line 0: continue: only meaningful in a ‘for’, ‘while’, or ‘until’ loop
a
environment: line 0: continue: only meaningful in a ‘for’, ‘while’, or ‘until’ loop
b
environment: line 0: continue: only meaningful in a ‘for’, ‘while’, or ‘until’ loop
c
done
```

Ksh silently ignores it:

```
$ ksh -c 'f() { continue; }; for x in a b c; do f; echo $x; done; echo done'
a
b
c
done
```

While Dash, Yash and Zsh actually do apply it:

```
$ dash -c 'f() { continue; }; for x in a b c; do f; echo $x; done; echo done'
done
```

I did expect similar considerations might apply to using `eval`, too, but it seems that's not the case. At least I can't see any differences between the shells.

All in all, don't do that. Just write it out:

```
while read -r var;
do
    if [[ $var =~  ^bar$  ]];
    then
        echo "skipping '$var'"
        continue
    fi
    echo "processed: $var"
done
```