# getting unexpected EOF error

Tags: shell-script

I am getting the following error

```
/tmp/filechecking.sh: line 11: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
/tmp/filechecking.sh: command substitution: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/tmp/filechecking.sh: command substitution: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/tmp/filechecking.sh: line 6: bad substitution: no closing "`" in `
echo "${filetype[@]}"
done
```

My script is

```
losystem=`ls /appl/vortex/archive/cons/*`
echo "${losystem[@]"
for indsystm in "${losystem[@]}"
do
filetype=`isql -UDAS -PCDRD -SYTRT_DCS_FRET << EOF
select  file_type  from expected_file where  starters_package_version = '4.0' and system_id = 'DAL'
go
EOF`
echo "${filetype[@]}"
done
```

Can somebody help what is the syntax error here'

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> losystem=`ls /appl/vortex/archive/cons/*`
> echo "${losystem[@]"
> for indsystm in "${losystem[@]}"
> do
> filetype=`isql -UDAS -PCDRD -SYTRT_DCS_FRET << EOF
> select  file_type  from expected_file where  starters_package_version = '4.0' and system_id = 'DAL'
> go
> EOF`
> echo "${filetype[@]}"
> done
> ```

The syntax error itself is caused by the backtick appearing on the same line as `EOF`, as indicated in [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341607/135943).  However, **this script has other problems,** so in the interest of better shell scripting abilities everywhere, let's take a closer look.

---

First misconception: As you reference `"${losystem[@]}"`, you seem to be under the impression that you have [created an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).  You haven't.  To do that, you need to use parentheses in your variable assignment.

Similarly, if you *do* use an array, you don't need to use `ls`.  The globs will expand directly to become the elements of the array.

This is fortunate, because you should never parse the output of `ls`, anyway; see:

- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943)

So the right way to set the variable `losystem` as an *array* whose elements are the files and directories inside `/appl/vortex/archive/cons/` is:

```
losystem=(/appl/vortex/archive/cons/*)
```

---

Your `echo` command (on the second line) is missing a closing `}`.

Also, you may want to use `printf` here instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "${losystem[@]}"
```

Also see:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

---

The `for` loop is correct for iterating over the elements of the Bash array `losystem`, so given that you've made the above corrections, you can use it unchanged.

However, you don't *need* to set an array, and it's much more *idiomatic* (cleaner, more intuitive) to directly state the file glob in the for loop:

```
for indsystem in /appl/vortex/archive/cons/*; do
```

This also has the advantage of being POSIX-compliant, since it doesn't rely on Bash arrays, so it can work in a wider variety of shells (i.e. it's more portable).

---

The next part of your script is even trickier to review, because it appears that you are setting `filetype` to the *output* of the `isql` command, but then you don't *do* anything with this output except print it—badly formatted—with `echo`.  (Again, see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943))

The obvious approach is not to set the variable at all, but just run the command directly; it will print its own output, which is all you really wanted anyway:

```
isql -UDAS -PCDRD -SYTRT_DCS_FRET << EOF
select  file_type  from expected_file where  starters_package_version = '4.0' and system_id = 'DAL'
go
EOF
```

Note that **I am not familiar with `isql`, so I do not attest the correctness of this command.**  It is the command you yourself wrote, unchanged.  It may or may not be correct.

---

The strangest thing about this script, though, is the fact that you are setting `indsystem` to each element of the `losystem` array (or trying to), but then **you never reference the value of `"$indsystem"`.**

This is the "elephant in the room."  I can't fix this logic, because I can't read your mind.  It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.

I can think of several different possibilities:

1. Perhaps you are trying to run the `isql` command on each file in the `cons` directory.  (In which case the `isql` command should reference the `indsystem` variable somewhere, and you should check that you don't run it on directories.)
2. Perhaps you want to run the `isql` command exactly once, but only if the `cons` directory is not empty.
3. Perhaps you want to run the `isql` command without referencing `indsystem`, but run it the same way multiple times, exactly as many times as there are files/directories in the `cons` directory.  (This is what my fixed version of the code will do, but it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.)

None of these possibilities are obviously correct, so I can't conclude what the script is actually trying to do.

Still, I hope this was helpful in learning more about shell scripting.  To learn Bash scripting properly, I recommend the [Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

---

I will also comment that in my professional experience, I have found that a shell script with as many problems as this one usually has architectural/design problems **at a higher level**, and that *usually* it is necessary to completely review the supposed reason why the script is needed in the first place to get a truly workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The end delimiter of the here-document should be alone on the line:

```
filetype=`isql -UDAS -PCDRD -SYTRT_DCS_FRET << EOF
select  file_type  from expected_file where  starters_package_version = '4.0' and system_id = 'DAL'
go
EOF
`
```

It is often recommended to use `$(...)` rather than backticks for new code, as `$(...)` have better nesting capabilities and in general just looks better:

```
filetype=$( isql -UDAS -PCDRD -SYTRT_DCS_FRET <<EOF
select  file_type 
  from  expected_file
  where starters_package_version = '4.0' 
    and system_id = 'DAL'
go
EOF
)
```

For information about why using `$(...)` may be preferrable, see "[Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)"