# How to force ssh to execute command on the remote system instead of locally

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have SSH executing some commands in a script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTEUSER=$1
REMOTEHOST=$2    
newVh=$3

ssh "$REMOTEUSER"@"$REMOTEHOST" << EOF

cd

if [ ! -d "/data/web/someDirectory" ]
then
  echo -e "There is no vhost setup for someDirectory"
  exit 1
fi


if [ ! -d "git" ]
then
  echo -e "Home git directory not found. Creating it now."
  mkdir git
fi

if [ ! -d "git/$newVh.git" ]
then
  echo -e "Bare git repository not found for $new. Creating it now."
  mkdir git/"$newVh".git
  git init --bare git/"$newVh".git
fi


EOF
```

Which works fine and does what I want. I'm trying to check if the `compass` ruby gem is installed on the remote machine and if it's not, I want to install it. I added this line to the bottom of the script:

```
.
.
.
if [ `gem list compass -i` == 'false' ]
then
  echo -e "Compass not installed... Installing it now."
  gem install compass -V
fi


EOF
```

But `` `gem list compass -i` ``. is getting evaluated on my local machine beforehand (I have compass installed). Even running `gem list compass -i` in the script with no quotes to see the output is returning `true` which is incorrect. I tried escaping the command with a number of `\`s but it didn't work.

I guess two questions:

How is it that other commands in the script (`mkdir`, `cd`, `git init` etc...) work correctly on the remote machine but `gem list` does not?

How do I escape that command to run it remotely?

Comment: You don't actually have dollar signs prefixing your variable assignments, do you?

Comment: Yeah the leading dollar `$PID_FILE=$(cat ...)` error caused a massive and very expensive outage at some previous workplace of mine... (standard error was redirected and sent to `/dev/null` a bunch of times to better hide the error)

Comment: Do you really have EOF twice ? the << EOF will match only the first one..

I would personally use rex (rexify.org) to execute staff on remote system(s) via ssh.

Comment: @JeffSchaller No. My bad. And the variable `new` isn't named `new` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that the command substitution expression (denoted by back-ticks) is evaluated prior to the execution of the `ssh` command. In a different situation you might consider quoting the here-doc keyword (e.g. "EOF") in order to prevent parameter expansion in your here-doc, but in this case you actually do want to perform some parameter substitution client-side. So a solution here could be to escape the command substitution. Try this instead:

```
if [ \`gem list compass -i\` == 'false' ]
then
  echo -e "Compass not installed... Installing it now."
  gem install compass -V
fi
```

The escaped back-ticks prevent the command substitution from being evaluated.

I'll also mention that the back-tick syntax for command substitution is widely considered to be a legacy feature and that the dollar-sign syntax is generally preferred nowadays. Here is what the above snippet would look like with the dollar-sign syntax instead:

```
if [ \$(gem list compass -i) == 'false' ]
then
  echo -e "Compass not installed... Installing it now."
  gem install compass -V
fi
```

For more information about the differences between the two notations, you can refer to the following StackExchange posts:

- [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)
- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)

You may also want to look at the [GNU Bash manual page on command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

And also at the [GNU Bash manual page on redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Note in particular the following subsection on here-docs:

> **3.6.6 Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is specified) for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>     here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or filename expansion is performed on *word*. If any part of *word* is quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.
>
> If the redirection operator is ‘<<-’, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing *delimiter*. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Comment: You've gone back and forth between backticks and the $() form and I was hoping you'd leave it with the $() form. Unless you want to run scripts with the ca .1976 Bourne shell, there is no reason to still be using backticks. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, I've made a bunch of edits. I decided that it was poor form to use a different syntax than what was in the question without any warning, so I went back to the back-tick syntax that Brandon was using. But then I thought better of it and added some references regarding command substitution. Better now, I hope?

Comment: Nice answer. I'll try the dollar sign syntax. I did try backslash escaping the backticks and it didn't work.

Comment: Turned out to be that `gem list -i` wants a regex and was returning a false positive on installation of `compass-core`. The dollar sign worked perfectly. Thanks.