# Bash - issue with grep conditional statement

Tags: bash, grep, test

Why does this code work correctly, while the other version of the same condition doesn't?

```
if grep -q string file; then
    echo found
else
    echo not found
fi
```

This doesn't work:

```
if [ ! `grep -q string file` ]; then
    echo not found
else
    echo found
fi
```

Comment: Why have you changed the syntax on the two examples?, just a ! to your original example

Comment: Do you know what `-q` does, or are you just blindly using it because you've seen others use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`` `grep -q string file` ``, in backticks (or inside `$(...)`, [which is preferable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)), will be replaced by the *output* of `grep`. This will be an empty string since `-q` is used.

To negate a test, just insert `!` before it:

```
if ! grep -q pattern file; then
    echo not found
else
    echo found
fi
```

If you truly want to search for a *string* (rather than a regular expression), then you should use `-F` with `grep` as well.