# Comparing two integer variables

Tags: bash, shell

I want to print two iterators named `i` and `j` of nested `for loops` whenever they are not equal. The error message:

> syntax error near unexpected token `then'

```
#!/bin/bash
read n
array=()
for i in `seq 1 $n`
do
    read num
    array+=$num
done

count=0
count2=0
countmax=0
for i in `seq 1 $n`; do
    for j in `seq 1 $n`; do
        if [ $i -ne $j ]; then
            echo $i $j
        fi
    done
done
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: works for me, though of course `n` should be set, `$(...)` is nicer than backticks and it might be prudent to quote the variables.

Comment: One potential reason for that error would be a non-breaking space or such instead of normal space after the `if`. That would make it a different word, not recognized as the `if` keyword. And then `then` would be misplaced. (it would be `if_[`, with `_` representing the nbsp)

Comment: Does it work if you copy the code from this page and run it?

Comment: `array+=$num` probably doesn't do what you want, you may want `array+=($num)` instead

Answer (score 1):

> What have I done wrong?

In no particular order,

- You didn't have `#!/bin/bash` or equivalent as the first line.
- You don't seem to have posted the actual script that's failing. (What you have here is syntactically correct.)
- You haven't double-quoted your variables, `"$n"` instead of `$n`.
- You're using obsolete backticks for evaluation instead of `$( ...)`.
- You haven't tested your code in https://shellcheck.net/
- You haven't indented your code blocks to make them easier to read.
- If you are adding elements to an array, use `array+=($num)`. What you have in your code is string concatenation to the last element.
- In the (new) first block you assign to elements (0 .. n-1) but you later use elements (1 .. n).
- In the (new) second block you are comparing the indices for inequality rather than the array elements. Did you mean to compare `"${array[$i]}" -ne "${array[$j]}"` (or, for the `(( ... ))` construct, `array[i] != array[j]`)?

(I should probably point out that some of these are good practice rather then essential coding rules.)

Here is your code with my suggestions applied:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Number of elements: ' n

array=(0)    # We don't use element zero
for i in $(seq "$n")
do
    read -p 'Element: ' num
    array+=($num)
done

for i in $(seq "$n")
do
    for j in $(seq "$n")
    do
        # Compare the array elements rather than the indices
        # Is this what you intended?
        if (( array[i] != array[j] ))
        then
            echo "${array[$i]} ${array[$j]}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Maybe slightly better (because easier to read): `if (( array[i] != array[j] ))`

Comment: @user1934428 ah yes. Good call. I'd switched from `[ ... ]` to `[[ ... ]]` and forgot that variables can be handled even better with `(( ... ))`.

Comment: @roaima Backticks are not obsolete (or even deprecated)  At best, their usage is not recommended.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I have to disagree with you on that point. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/100397 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 and the POSIX statement about `$(...)` being preferred at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03

Comment: @roaima.  Good to see that you went to the ONLY authoritative source on the issue, i.e. POSIX.  Please  explain how the term you used, i..e "obsolete" is equivalent to the term POSIX uses, i.e. "preferred".  BTW, neither of the other two sources you quote are authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

I would also eliminate the use of `seq` by using for loops:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Number of elements: ' n

array=(0)
for (( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ))
do
    read -p 'Element: ' num
    array+=("$num")
done

for (( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ))
do
    for (( j = 1; j <= n; j++ ))
    do
        (( array[i] != array[j] )) && echo "${array[i]} ${array[j]}"
    done
done
```