# How to create user and password in one script for 100+ users

Tags: bash, password, command, useradd, multiuser

I have written a script for adding and setting password for 100+ users. Eg: for setting password of the user I want to set in "user+123" format for all the users I.e user will change according to the username in password. 
How can I write a script for this.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `more users.txt`
do
useradd $i;
echo "User $i added successfully"
passwd $("$i"123)
echo "Password added successfully for user"
done
```

Comment: Please do not use photos were text will do. It is not *that difficult* typing in that script.

Comment: I would look at changing the passwords for users in batch mode using chpasswd.

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( cat users.txt ); do
    useradd $i
    echo "user $i added successfully!"
    echo $i:$i"123" | chpasswd
    echo "Password for user $i changed successfully"
done
```

This little script should be what you are looking for. It adds the user first, then proceeds to change the password. Avoid using backticks, as they are deprecated, `$()` is a good alternative.

Comment: Please give a reason for the downvote, maybe I can learn something, something I did wrong?

Comment: Where do you see that back ticks are deprecated? It says nothing about that in the official manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: @NathanAdams, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/237568

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Works like a charm , thanks alot

Comment: ksh is not bash, and as an AIX developer for many years, there is a lot of syntax out there that is "deprecated", or undocumented (IBM internal use only stuff). Sitewide on SE there is *one* mention of lquerypv for instance. Bash on AIX supports backticks, but you would need to have it installed.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers provide technical answers for how to do this. But please don't do this.

As soon as a threat actor sees the pattern, they could log in as any other user. (And even if you force a password change on first login, someone could lock out all of the other users.)

Instead, send each user a random password, or a token via email to be used to set a new password.

Answer (score 1):

In below script i am creating  5 users like user1,user2,user3,user4,user5 and setting the pasword as "username+123" for each user Tested and it worked successfully.

You can change number of users as per requirment

```
for i in user{1..5}; do useradd $i; passwd -d $i; echo $i"123" | passwd  $i --stdin; done
```

If you have a text file in which you have specific usernames, you can use

```
for i in $(cat users.txt); do useradd $i; passwd -d $i; echo $i"123" | passwd  $i --stdin; done
```

Comment: OP wants the users to have unique names, and the password should be $user123, your answer does not accommodate that.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Edited the answer  and changed as per the requirement and tested too . its working fine

Comment: I edited your answer to properly show what the OP needs to do when the usernames are in a textfile.