# how to set and unset proxy dynamically through shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

```
p=sudo npm config get proxy;
echo "$p";
if [ -z $p ] 
 then
  echo "delete";
  sudo npm config delete proxy http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8085
 else 
 echo "set";
  sudo npm config set proxy http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8085
fi
```

I have tried this but didn't get result

Answer (score 4):

There wasn't too much wrong with your script:

1. setting a variable to the output of a command (i.e. [Command Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution)) needs `$()` around the command.  I am deliberately ignoring the existence of obsolete backticks for the same purpose, they are broken in several ways.
2. quote your variables when you use them.

   e.g. `if [ -z $p ]` without quotes is guaranteed to be a syntax error if `$p` is actually empty because `-z` **requires** an argument.  `if [ -z "$p" ]` will never cause an error because even an empty string is an argument.

Here's a minimally fixed version (also with superfluous semicolons removed):

```bash
p="$(sudo npm config get proxy)"
echo "$p"
if [ -z "$p" ] ; then
  echo "delete"
  sudo npm config delete proxy http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8085
else 
  echo "set"
  sudo npm config set proxy http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8085
fi
```

Comment: BTW, the `-z` probably needs to be a `-n`.   The way it's written now, it attempts to delete the proxy setting if `"$p"` is empty (i.e. no proxy has been configured) which effectively does nothing, and sets a proxy if one is already set.    But that's what I meant by "minimally fixed" - I fixed the obvious errors, without any consideration of whether your script actually does what you want/expect or not....I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Mind expanding on your comment on why backticks are "broken in several ways"?

Comment: quoting issues. you can't nest backticks.  difficult to distinguish from single-quotes.  general ugliness.  some (unverified) reports of demonic manifestations. see, e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst.  backticks still work (as well...badly...as they ever did) but don't use them. backticks are evil, and they will cause your hamster to spontaneously explode.

Comment: But ... I don't have a hamster. Now I'm even more worried.

Comment: i accidentally deleted the chilling end to that sentence - "even if you don't have a hamster".

Comment: No it doesnot solve my problem , it is going in if condition only , not matching 'null" @cas

Comment: i want to toggle proxy, if set then delete or vice versa.

Comment: if `npm config get proxy` returns the string `null` rather than an empty string, then test for `[ "$p" == 'null' ]` rather than `[ -z "$p" ]` - is that somehow not completely obvious?