# awk in ssh command line complains 'unexpected newline or end of string' How to resolve?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, awk, scripting, quoting

While running the below script had an issue, ^ unexpected newline or end of string
How could I resolve this ?

```
[root@emrbldbgdapd2 ~]# ./collectdata.sh
collect the data of 10.209.61.124
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
collect the data of 10.209.61.125
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
[root@emrbldbgdapd2 ~]#
==========
[root@emrbldbgdapd2 ~]# more collectdata.sh
for i in `cat test`
do echo "collect the data of $i"
ssh -o LogLevel=error -o ConnectTimeout=5 $i 'hostname;
echo "############################";
free -g;
echo "######################################";
echo "######################################";
netstat -nr | grep [0-9] | tr [a-z] [A-Z];
echo "######################################";
echo "######################################";
mount|awk '{print $1,$3,$5}'|sort;
echo "######################################";
echo "######################################";
ip a s | grep -i eth*;
echo "######################################"'>output/$i-`date "+%d%b%Y"`
done
[root@emrbldbgdapd2 ~]#
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please do select one of the answers below so others may see that your issue was solved and can use the answer in case of need. To do so, select the green check mark left of the best reply. It is greyed out when not selected and located just below the karma point counter.

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to use single quotes within a singly-quoted string.  The first internal single quote, on the same line as the `mount | awk | sort` pipeline, will terminate the single quote that is started on the `ssh` line.

The actual error comes from `awk`. It gets handed a command line that looks something like `{print ,,}` (due to `$1`, `$3`, `$5` being expanded to empty strings by the calling shell and the single quotes being absent at this point). This is interpreted as an `awk` program with a syntax error (missing `}`) to be run on a file called `,,}`.

I'd recommend to put the script in an actual script file and that you run this on the remote host instead, to avoid quoting issues and to allow you to create a more maintainable procedure.

Furthermore,

1. Use `read` in a `while`-loop rather than doing a `for`-loop over the result of `cat`.
2. The internal script in particular lacks necessary quoting in several places.  This is needed so that e.g. `grep [0-9]` won't trigger filename globbing.
3. `grep eth*` looks odd. Did you mean `grep -e 'eth.'`?  Apart from acting as a filename globbing pattern that would pick up any name in the current directory that starts with `eth`, the pattern (if interpreted as a regular expression) would match `et` followed by zero or more `h`.
4. See [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) regarding your use of backticks.

Modified script:

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$( date +%d%b%Y )

if [ -d output ]; then
    echo 'Output directory missing' >&2
    exit 1
fi

while read host; do
    printf 'Collecting data from "%s"...\n' "$host"

    ssh -n -o LogLevel=error -o ConnectTimeout=5 "$host" \
      sh <<'END_SCRIPT' >output/"$host-$now"
        echo '## HOSTNAME:'
        hostname
        echo '## FREE:'
        free -g
        echo '## NETSTAT:'
        netstat -nr | grep '[0-9]' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
        echo '## MOUNT:'
        mount | awk '{ print $1, $3, $5 }' | sort
        echo '## IP:'
        ip a s | grep -i 'eth.*'
END_SCRIPT
done <hosts.txt
```

Comment: +1 for yr advice to use `read` in a `while` rather than `cat` in a `for`.

Comment: If you use `ssh` within a while-read loop, you should use `-n` otherwise the first `ssh` will consume all the input.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other answers, the issues is with using single-quotes in the command you're running on the remote. As the syntax-coloring here on SE shows, the `{print $1,$3,$5}` is not quoted, and the single-quotes around it don't reach the remote shell.

One way to work around that would be to send the script to the remote through stdin with a here-doc:

```
ssh somehost /bin/sh > outputfile <<"EOF"
hostname
free -g
netstat -nr | grep "[0-9]" | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
mount | awk '{print $1,$3,$5}' | sort
# and so on
EOF
```

Put the here-doc separator `"EOF"` in quotes, so that the `$1` variables aren't expanded by the local shell. That should take care of the quoting issues with the local shell, but you still need to quote stuff for the remote, like anything that looks like a glob (`[0-9` and `foo*`).

`tr` doesn't need the brackets for the `a-z` arguments (they don't do any harm, they just tell it to change a `[` to a `[` and the same with `]`). Though I think the output of that `netstat` contains the interface names, and uppercasing them will make the names different.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
mount|awk '{print $1,$3,$5}'|sort;
```

To:

```
mount|awk '\''{print $1,$3,$5}'\''|sort;
```

Comment: That should fix the problem of the awk script getting split, but then the remote shell would expand the `$1` and others before awk sees them. So you need `' ... | awk "{print \$1,\$3,\$5}" | ...'` or `' ... | awk '\''{print $1,$3,$5}'\'' | ...'` or such