# I don't understand what a single backtick and double quote and >> do in this script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

This example was in a Linux book:

```
$ cat sort-wc
#!/bin/bash
# Sort files according to their line count
for f
do
    echo `wc -l <"$f» lines in $f
done | sort -n
$ ./sort-wc /etc/passwd /ect/fstab /etc/motd
```

What I don't get is why there is only a single backtick, a single double quote and what the `>>` does.  Isn't `>>` for writing to a file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is from page 121 of ["Introduction to Linux
for Users and Administrators"](https://www.tuxcademy.org/download/en/grd1/grd1-en-manual.pdf) and that's a typographical error in the text. The script is also avaliable in other texts from tuxcademy, with the same typographical error.

The single `»` character is not the same as the double `>>` and it serves no purpose in a shell script. My guess is that the typesetting system used for formatting the text of the book got confused by `` "` `` for some reason and formatted it as a guillemet (angle-quote), or it's just a plain typo (the `«...»` quotes are used for quoting ordinary text elsewhere in the document).

The script should read

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sort files according to their line count
for f
do
    echo `wc -l <"$f"` lines in $f
done | sort -n
```

... but would be better written

```
#!/bin/sh
# Sort files according to their line count

for f; do
    printf '%d lines in %s\n' "$(wc -l <"$f")" "$f"
done | sort -n
```

The backticks are an older form of `$( ... )`, and `printf` is better to use for outputting variable data. Also, variable expansions and command substitutions should be quoted, and the script uses no `bash` features so it could just as well be executed by `/bin/sh`.

Related:

- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Wow thank you, yes that's exactly where this example is from.  I'll need to comb over your better second resolution because that confusing me more, I'm an extreme beginner at shell scripting :)

Comment: @user284179 Once you figure out how `printf` works (see `man 1 printf`, it takes a format string followed by other arguments to substitute into the placeholders in the format string), it will be clear.

Comment: Your guess about the typesetting error is very plausible. The quote used to be an active character in German LaTeX packages to be able to type ä as “a.  With the *german* package, the combination in question should produce German opening quotation marks, but maybe the author used a variant that gives Swiss quotation marks.

Comment: I think I've seen `/bin/sh` implementations which support backticks but not `$(...)`, so beware of portability issues.

Comment: Fun fact: https://github.com/nyucel/linuxessentials contains a TEX copy of this book — in, apparently, Turkish — posted by [Necdet Yucel](https://github.com/nyucel).  As I mentioned, the text is apparently in Turkish (as identified by [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Linux'a%20Giri%C5%9F)), except the Preface and the examples are in English. https://github.com/nyucel/linuxessentials/blob/master/bolum9.tex is Chapter 9, which contains the example this question is about — but it gets it right: `echo \`wc -l <"$f"\` lines in $f` (see lines 435-444).

Comment: @grawity If you have a system with a non-POSIX `/bin/sh`, then it's so old that you should not be doing development work on it. If it's a production system, it should seriously be considered for replacing as it would potentially be insecure if connected to the internet.

Comment: guillemets are used in a number of languages for quoting, but not english or german. As the answer says, this is probably an example of slightly sloppy typesetting (using automatic smart quotes + not properly declaring a code environment probably).