# What is a chmod equivalent of mesg

Tags: chmod

What is a `chmod` equivalent for `mesg y` and `mesg n`?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Do you want to make `mesg` settings depend on user(s) and group(s)?

Answer (score 8):

Note: As JdeBP [points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442029/what-is-a-chmod-equivalent-of-mesg/442032?noredirect=1#comment800013_442032), it is non-trivial to reproduce the behaviour of `mesg` with `chmod`.

[The Rationale section in the POSIX specification for `mesg`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/mesg.html) says

> **The terminal changed by `mesg` is that associated with the standard input, output, or error, rather than the controlling terminal for the session**. This is because users logged in more than once should be able to change any of their login terminals without having to stop the job running in those sessions. This is not a security problem involving the terminals of other users because appropriate privileges would be required to affect the terminal of another user.
>
> The method of checking each of the first three file descriptors in sequence until a terminal is found was adopted from System V.

*The naive approach* would be to look at the changes in permissions on the shell's controlling terminal (the device that the current interactive shell's standard input is attached to) when `mesg` is used.

The controlling terminal of the shell is returned by the `tty` command. To figure out what `mesg n` and `mesg y` are doing with the permissions on the device, we can use `ls -l` on it and see what changes:

```
$ ls -l "$(tty)"
crw--w----  1 myself  tty    5,   1 May  6 00:21 /dev/ttyp1

$ mesg n
$ ls -l "$(tty)"
crw-------  1 myself  tty    5,   1 May  6 00:21 /dev/ttyp1

$ mesg y
$ ls -l "$(tty)"
crw--w----  1 myself  tty    5,   1 May  6 00:21 /dev/ttyp1
```

So it looks like `mesg n` removes the group write permission for the device (`rw--w----` changes to `rw-------`) and `mesg y` adds the group write permission again.

The `chmod` equivalent would, in my case, be

```
$ chmod g-w "$(tty)"     # for "mesg n"
$ chmod g+w "$(tty)"     # for "mesg y"
```

Add salt and pepper appropriately for you particular flavour of Unix.

Note, though, that if the shell's standard input is not a terminal, `tty` would return the string `not a tty` and the `chmod` would fail. In this scenario, `mesg` would go on to try with the terminal device for the shell's standard output and then standard error (in that order).  This is why the above is a *naive* approach.

Comment: You could change `"$(tty)"` to `"\`tty\`"` to make it more portable to other shells than `bash` (e.g. the code does not work in `tcsh`).

Comment: @Ned64 Um, no.  I'm running this in `/bin/sh` (not `bash`) which is a shell that exists on all Unix systems. `/bin/sh` understands `$(...)` as a command substitution (unless the system is very old indeed, and has skipped more than a few updates). For more about that, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated

Comment: @Kusalananda what is the difference between running `chmod g-w` and `chmod g-w "$(tty)"`? (New to UNIX and trying to make sure I understand)

Comment: `ll ($tty)` yields `Badly placed ()'s.` in my shell. Anyway, please `ll /bin/sh` - in GNU/Linux often a link to `bash`, they share a syntax. `ksh`, `tcsh`, ... vary in syntax.

Comment: @Ned64 I believe I used `$(tty)`, not `($tty)`.  My `/bin/sh` happens to be `ksh` in POSIX mode.

Comment: Sorry.  `ll $(tty)` yields `Illegal variable name.`.  Interesting, so it does work in `ksh`.  It does not in `csh`+`tcsh`.

Comment: @MandyLB The `tty` command returns the current terminal device. This is the file that changes permission when you use `mesg`. The command `chmod g-w "$(tty)"` removes the write permission for the current terminal device. `chmod g-w` by itself is nonsensical as the command is not given a filename to change permission on.

Comment: @Ned64 `csh` and `tcsh` uses a totally different shell dialect from the `sh` shells (`bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `zsh`, etc.). They can't really be compared, and trying to write polyglot shell code that works (without errors) in both `sh` and `csh` shells is really something you should avoid.

Comment: A subtlety of `mesg` not reflected in this answer is that `mesg` _does not_ operate upon the controlling terminal.  Depending from which operating system's `mesg` it is, it operates upon the standard error or the first of standard input/output/error that is a terminal device.  This is non-trivial to duplicate, and would not involve the `tty` command.  One example in one `mesg` manual page even demonstrates standard input redirected from _some other_ terminal and not the controlling terminal.

Comment: @JdeBP You are absolutely correct. I will amend the answer by referring to your comment.