# Explanation of `sed` usage in specific shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

While reading [an online tutorial](https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hwloidl/Courses/LinuxIntro/x945.html), I came across the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Counting the number of lines in a list of files
# for loop over arguments
# count only those files I am owner of

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 file ..."
  exit 1
fi

echo "$0 counts the lines of code" 
l=0
n=0
s=0
for f in $*
do
  if [ -O $f ] # checks whether file owner is running the script
  then 
      l=`wc -l $f | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
      echo "$f: $l"
      n=$[ $n + 1 ]
      s=$[ $s + $l ]
  else
      continue
  fi
done

echo "$n files in total, with $s lines in total"
```

What is the purpose of the `sed` call in this example?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy and paste the text directly into the question in a code block.  Also if this is coursework I recommend finding another course.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me!  it was a very hard for me to learn linux from the internet and i do realise now that this coursework is a little bit unefficient  :)

Comment: But i still have a little problem ...and i would be very grateful if you could give me one more helping hand. Having read your answer, i understood the output of the sed function, but i want you to explain me step by step what sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'` means ( why did they choose that arguments) :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain in more detail.

Comment: Wooooow!thanks! Now everything makes sense!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command in example 6 pulls only the number of lines out of the `wc -l` output.

It's running `wc -l` on `$f` (the file owned by the running of the script that was passed in as an argument).  This would normally produce an output like so:

```
$ wc -l .bashrc
17 .bashrc
```

Number of lines in column 1 and filename in column 2.  The `sed` command is grabbing only the number of lines in a pretty unnecessary way.

```
$ wc -l .bashrc | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
17
```

The `sed` statement `'s/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'` does the following:

- `^` - Match the beginning of the line
- `\([0-9]*\)` - Match any numbers unlimited times (The escaped parenthesis form a capture group)
- `.*` - Match anything unlimited times
- `$` - Match the end of the line
- `\1` - Represents the contents of the first capture group.

Essentially this is matching any line that starts with a number and replacing the whole line with the first capture group (the number).

---

Thanks Stephen Kitt for recommending this:

```
$ wc -l < .bashrc
17
```

---

Otherwise using `cut` or `awk` would be better for something like this:

```
$ wc -l .bashrc | cut -d' ' -f1
17

$ wc -l .bashrc | awk '{print $1}'
17
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `sed` in that piece of code is to parse the output of `wc -l` to extract the number of lines in the file.

This is usually not needed as

```
l=$( wc -l <"$f" )
```

would have done the same thing (you should try this).

---

The script is using a few constructs that are non-portable and considered "obsolete", and there are details in the script that makes it unsafe.

1. Expansions should be quoted.  For example, `if [ $# -lt 1 ]` is better written as `if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]`, and `if [ -O $f ]` should be `if [ -O "$f" ]`.  This way we can support filenames that contain any characters, even characters that are part of `$IFS` (spaces, tabs and newlines).  The `$#` should be quoted in case `$IFS` contains digits for some reason or other.

   For more on this, see the three other questions entitled "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)", "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)" and "[When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)".
2. Command substitution using backticks is troublesome under some circumstances.  The line saying `` l=`wc -l ...` `` could be rewritten as `l=$(wc -l ...)`.  The newer `$(...)` is better since it nests, since quoting works as expected (compare e.g. `` echo "`echo "`echo ok`"`" ``, which generates a syntax error, with `echo "$(echo "$(echo ok)")"`), and since it is easier to read.

   For more on this, see e.g. "[Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)"
3. `$[ $s + $l ]` is a non-portable way of saying `$(( s + l ))`.
4. Variable data should be outputted using `printf` rather than by using `echo`.  For example, that last line,

   ```
   echo "$n files in total, with $s lines in total"
   ```

   may be rewritten as

   ```
   printf '%d files in total, with %d lines in total\n' "$n" "$s"
   ```

   See e.g. "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)".
5. Using `$*` to loop over the command line arguments stops the script from functioning on filenames containing spaces.
6. The `continue` statement and the `else` branch of the `if` statement is not needed at all as it comes last in the loop anyway.
7. Diagnostic output should be printed to standard error.

"Corrected" version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Counting the number of lines in a list of files
# for loop over arguments
# count only those files I am owner of

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    printf 'Usage: %s file ...\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf '%s counts the lines of code\n' "$0"
l=0; n=0; s=0
for name do
    if [ -f "$name" ] && [ -O "$name" ]; then # checks whether its a regular file and file owner is running the script
        nlines=$( wc -l <"$name" )
        printf '%s: %d\n' "$name" "$nlines"
        totlines=$(( totlines + nlines ))
        nfiles=$(( nfiles + 1 ))
    fi
done

printf '%d files in total, with %s lines in total" "$nfiles" "$totlines"
```