# wc -c not working in a loop in the script

Tags: bash

So I'm writing a simple script that checks if the size of the file is less than the given argument and if its true then its suppose to echo "YES"

```
#!bin/bash

Function ()
{
    cd $1
    lista=`ls`
    for item in $lista
    do
        if [ ! -d $item ]
        then
            size=`wc -c $item | awk '{ print $1 }'`
            if [ $size -lt $2 ]
            then
                echo "$item"
            fi
        else
            Function $item $2
        fi
        cd ..
    done
}

Function $1 $2
```

And the bash:

```
bash test2.sh /home/161161 300
```

However something is wrong with the wc -c because it gives me the error that no such file or exist after running through the second loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be relevant here: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Soo a solution?

Comment: It's hard to tell, because the script as written is very brittle. It should [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [should not parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), should use `[[` instead of `[`. For readability it should also use a different name than `Function` (which is only an uppercase away from a Bash keyword) and should be indented properly.

Comment: You don't need a script for this, just `find /dir -size -300c` will list the full filenames; if you really want ony the last branch, which seems unlikely to be useful, add `-printf %s` or pipe the output through `sed 's:.*/::'` or `awk -F/ '{print $NF}'` . If you really want a script, you can avoid the `awk` for each file by using redirection `wc -c <"$file"` so the `wc` output is only the number and no filename.

Comment: The `wc -c <"$file"` will read the contents of each and every file to count the number of bytes. You can get the file size directly with `stat -c %s "$file"`. But as has already been pointed out you can just use `find`.

Comment: ... or `stat -f %z` on a BSD system.

Comment: @DavidMathers : BTW, you can simplify your size calculation to `size=$(wc -c <$item)`. If you write it like this, you don't need awk.

Comment: If you were to indent the loop and the conditional properly, it'd be easier to see that the `cd ..` is inside the loop, so it will run for every file...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your code is doing `cd ..` before being done with all the files in a directory. In general, you don't have to `cd` into directories to get filenames from them, and going back and forth into directories in loops can be confusing.  It can also lead to strange issues if you are redirecting output to filenames with relative paths, etc. inside the loops.  In this script, you also would not know *where* (in what directory) the file was found, because you always look in the current directory.

Fixing this by not using `cd`, and also by not using `ls`, which allows the script to work with filenames that have spaces and other unusual characters in them:

```
#!/bin/sh

find_smaller () {
    dir=$1
    size=$2

    for pathname in "$dir"/*; do
        if [ -f "$pathname" ]; then
            # this is a regular file (or a symbolic link to one), test its size
            filesize=$( wc -c <"$pathname" )
            if [ "$filesize" -lt "$size" ]; then
                printf 'Found %s, size is %d\n' "$pathname" "$filesize"
            fi
        elif [ -d "$pathname" ]; then
            # this is a directory (or a symbolic link to one), recurse
            printf 'Entering %s\n' "$pathname"
            find_smaller "$pathname" "$size"
        fi
    done
}

find_smaller "$@"
```

In the code above, `$pathname` will be not only the filename of the current file or directory that we're looking at, but also its path relative to the starting directory.

Note also the quoting of all variable expansions. Without quoting the `$pathname` variable, for example, you would invoke filename globbing if a filename contained characters like `*` or `?`.

See also:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)

---

Using `bash` and its `globstar` shell option. With this option set, the `**` glob pattern matches all the pathnames beneath the given directory. This means we don't have to explicitly walk the directory structure in our script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"
size="$2"

shopt -s globstar

for pathname in "$dir"/**; do
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue

    filesize=$( wc -c <"$pathname" )

    if [ "$filesize" -lt "$size" ]; then
        printf 'Found %s, size is %d\n' "$pathname" "$filesize"
    fi
done
```

---

Rather than writing your own directory tree walker, you may instead use `find`.  The following `find` command does what your code tries to do:

```
find /home/161161 -type f -size -100c
```

As a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=$1
size=$2
find "$dir" -type f -size -"$size"c
```

The only slight difference between the explicit directory walker and the `find` variation is that `find` (when used as above) will ignore symbolic links, while the shell function above it will resolve symbolic links, possibly causing directory loops to be traversed infinitely, or the same data to be counted more than once.

Using `find`, the contents of the files will not be read to figure out the file size.  Instead a `lstat()` library call will be made to query the filesystem for the file's size.  This is *many* times faster than using `wc -c`!

On most (but not all) Unices, you may also use the command line utility `stat` to get the file size.  See the manual for this utility on your system for how to use it (it works differently on Linux and BSD).

Comment: `stat -c %s` instead of `wc -c`. Or did you want to keep as much of the original code as possible in your first rewrite?

Comment: @roaima I wanted to use `wc` since that was in the title, also, my `stat` does not have `-c` (I'm on OpenBSD and the correct `stat` call would be `stat -f %z filename`).  We don't know what Unix this is supposed to run on.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't checked POSIX, and just assumed -c was standard. My bad. I might well be on my way (back to) one of the BSDs next refresh.

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem. However now I'm left with even more question. Like how is it possible for the script to do a cd .. before the loop has finished when the cd .. command is written after the loop?

Comment: @DavidMathers Look at your code. The `cd ..` is executed just before the end of the loop.

Comment: Oh my god how did I not notice that... Thank you so much