# How to cut a string based on delimiter which is having space

Tags: cut

```
variable_list="
 any:any:-a -b -c any
 one:one:-c -b -f -m mul
 mul:one:-c -b -f -m mul
"
for f in `echo $variable_list`
do
  c1=`echo $f | cut -d':' -f1`;
  c2=`echo $f | cut -d':' -f2`;
  c3=`echo $f | cut -d':' -f3-`;
  echo "c1==>$c1 and c2==>$c2 and c3==>$c3";
  #exit 0; ###I made mistake here
done;
```

Expected Output:

```
c1==>any and c2==>any and c3==>-a -b -c any
c1==>one and c2==>one and c3==>-c -b -f -m mul
c1==>mul and c2==>one and c3==>-c -b -f -m mul
```

Edit 1:

I realized that I was stupid while using the script and at first iteration I used `exit 0` to test it only first line since I have lots of this in real. It was working as it has to be.

Can I achieve the mentioned output by maintaining the `variable_list` with out modifying the format/way of input?

(I am using bash)

Comment: cannot reproduce here; is that the exact and complete command you're running?

Comment: `cut -d: -f3 < input` works; as does `cut -d: -f3- < input`

Comment: I am using inside a variable, I will add more information in the question.

Comment: How are you using the variable and how do you assign to the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue are with the spaces in the data.  The shell will split the string into words on all spaces and the `for` loop will iterate over those words.

(For a solution that does not replace `variable_list` with an array, see the very end of this answer.)

Instead, use a proper array:

```
variable_list=(
    "any:any:-a -b -c any"
    "one:one:-c -b -f -m mul"
    "mul:one:-c -b -f -m mul"
)

for var in "${variable_list[@]}"; do
    c1=$( cut -d':' -f1  <<<"$var" )
    c2=$( cut -d':' -f2  <<<"$var" )
    c3=$( cut -d':' -f3- <<<"$var" )
    printf 'c1==>%s and c2==>%s and c3==>%s\n' "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done
```

Using an array ensures that you can access each individual set of variables as its own array entry without relying on them being delimited by newlines or some other character.

The code is also using "here-strings" in `bash` to send the string to `cut` (rather than `echo` and a pipe).

Or, much more efficiently,

```
variable_list=(
    "any:any:-a -b -c any"
    "one:one:-c -b -f -m mul"
    "mul:one:-c -b -f -m mul"
)

for var in "${variable_list[@]}"; do
    IFS=':' read -r c1 c2 c3 <<<"$var"
    printf 'c1==>%s and c2==>%s and c3==>%s\n' "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done
```

Setting `IFS` to a colon for `read` will make `read` split the input on colons (rather than on spaces, tabs and newlines).

Note that all the quotation above is significant. Without the double quotes, the shell would perform word splitting and filename globbing on the values of `variable_list`, `var` and the three `c` variables.

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)

---

If all you're after is that specific output, then you may cheat a bit:

```
variable_list=(
    "any:any:-a -b -c any"
    "one:one:-c -b -f -m mul"
    "mul:one:-c -b -f -m mul"
)

( IFS=':'; set -f; printf 'c1==>%s and c2==>%s and c3==>%s\n' ${variable_list[@]} )
```

This runs the `printf` in a subshell so that setting `IFS` and the `-f` (`noglob`) shell option does not affect the rest of the script.  Setting `IFS` to a colon here will make the shell expand the *unquoted* `variable_list` array into three sets of three arguments for `printf`.  `printf` will print the first three according to its format string and then reuse that format for the next set of three arguments, until all arguments have been processed.

The `set -f` prevents the unquoted expansion of `variable_list` from triggering filename globbing, should there be any filename globbing characters in there.

---

Using a newline-delimited string:

```
variable_list="
any:any:-a -b -c any
one:one:-c -b -f -m mul
mul:one:-c -b -f -m mul"

while IFS= read -r var; do
    IFS=':' read -r c1 c2 c3 <<<"$var"
    printf 'c1==>%s and c2==>%s and c3==>%s\n' "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done <<<"$variable_list"
```

This reads the data from the string as if it came from a file.

Related:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to get your output :

```
echo "$variable_list" | awk -F: '
{
  sub("^ ","")
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    sub(/^/,"c" i "==>",$i)
}1' OFS=" and "
```