# How to extract an output from JSON to a shellscript variable?

Tags: linux, shell-script, json

What i did?

```
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# Group_ID=`/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get groups -r TEST`

[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# echo $Group_ID
[ { "id" : "57c86153-11ba-4d19-aafb-9903ee00086b", "name" : "Admin_UserGroup", "path" : "/Admin_UserGroup", "subGroups" : [ ] } ]
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# SURE_USER_ID=`echo $Group_ID | cut -d : -f2 | awk -F\" '{print $2}'`
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# echo $SURE_USER_ID
57c86153-11ba-4d19-aafb-9903ee00086b
```

In this case i am able to get the id but my requirement little bit complex 
I run below command

```
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]#  Group_ID=`/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get groups -r My_Realm`
```

and then

```
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# echo $Group_ID
```

Output was multiple record in JSON format

```
[ { "id" : "e27206c0-aeb6-43db-acda-c4ba43233071", "name" : "A1", "path" : "/A1", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "89f3bd6a-33a9-4e02-9fe3-eae660c5a6cf", "name" : "Admin_UserGroup", "path" : "/Admin_UserGroup", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "cdc2bce5-c3bb-4b88-bdaf-d87b8bb6c644", "name" : "Group104", "path" : "/Group104", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "a0d749f2-ab6c-4c27-ad55-3357eaab9527", "name" : "Group105", "path" : "/Group105", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "fbf99c34-d50d-408b-8d19-9713f9af3e3a", "name" : "Group106", "path" : "/Group106", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "ebd8336f-4017-4fb1-8035-153ae1d9ba37", "name" : "Group201", "path" : "/Group201", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "38f4aef7-caf0-4430-9e61-1ae7026e872f", "name" : "Group202", "path" : "/Group202", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "436a0f4a-8b1b-4d7d-a014-fcec3513644e", "name" : "Group203", "path" : "/Group203", "subGroups" : [ ] }, 
{ "id" : "41962c5f-e7e9-4748-b81f-e3f1880b78de", "name" : "Sure_Groups", "path" : "/Sure_Groups", "subGroups" : []}]
```

Now from the above output i want to get the `ID` where `name = Admin_UserGroup`.

How can this will achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a language that comes bundled with a JSON parsing library:

```
echo "$Group_ID" | python -c '
  import fileinput
  import json

  json_data = ""
  for line in fileinput.input():
    json_data = json_data + line

  data = json.loads(json_data)
  for o in data:
    if o["name"] == "Admin_UserGroup":
      print o["id"]
'
```

```
89f3bd6a-33a9-4e02-9fe3-eae660c5a6cf
```

Comment: How it can be done from awk or sed?

Comment: Why not python? `awk` or `sed` are not good in parsing JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` string for the `Admin_UserGroup` may be had with

```
Group_ID=$( /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get groups -r TEST )
SURE_USER_ID=$( printf '%s' "$Group_ID" | jq -r '.[]|select(.name == "Admin_UserGroup").id' )
```

If you don't need `Group_ID` for anything else:

```
SURE_USER_ID=$( /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get groups -r TEST | jq -r '.[]|select(.name == "Admin_UserGroup").id' )
```

This uses  [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON document document with a simple query that returns the `id` field for the array entries whose `name` is equal to `Admin_UserGroup`.

Related:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,in my case i am getting jq not found ,do i have to install some other library ? Is this possible to get the data without jq help?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi You would have to install the `jq` program.  Use your ordinary package manager to locate and install it.

Comment: Is this possible to do it without use of this library .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Yes, there are several other libraries for parsing JSON available. I'm don't have the time right now to write another answer though. I'm sure someone will come up with same `awk` or `sed` answer that might work.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no tool or library for json parsing installed and you can't install any or can't use any portable one, if if you can make some assumptions on the format of the json file (like it's always one space on either side of the `:`, there's no escaped character, no `{`, `}` in string values, no nested `{...}` ...) as seems it would be possible from your sample:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get groups -r My_Realm |
  perl -l -0777 -ne 'for (/\{.*?\}/sg) {
    print $1 if /"name" : "Admin_UserGroup"/ && /"id" : "(.*?)"/}'
```

For a more bullet-proof version:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'while(m(([^{}"]++|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*+"|
  \{(?:"name"\s*:\s*("Admin_UserGroup")|"id"\s*:\s*"((?:\\.|[^\\"])*+)"|
  (?1))*\}))gxs) {print $3 if $2}'
```