# How to pass variable from one function to another function

Tags: shell, scripting

```
updateEnvironmentField() {

          linewithoutquotes=`echo $LINE | tr -d '"'`
             b()
}
```

I want to pass variable named $linewithoutquotes to another method called b(), which is called from updateEnvironmentField() method. How to do the above requirement with shell script

Comment: Is there any reason why just put `$linewithoutquotes` inside `b()`? `b()` will be invoked in a subshell and its environment will differ from others.

Comment: A few options... make it a global variable, or pass in the value of your desired variable as an argument to the other function to name two of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
b () {
    arg=$1
    # more code here
}

updateEnvironmentField () {
    linewithoutquotes=`echo $LINE | tr -d '"'`
    b "$linewithoutquotes"
}
```

Here, we call `b` with the the result of your command substitution as a string.  The `b` function receives the string in the variable `arg`.

Note that you will want to use `printf` in place of `echo` and that you will need to properly quote the `$LINE` expansion so that whitespaces and globbing characters etc. are not messing up your data (I'm also changing the backticks to `$(...)` since that's more well behaved):

```
updateEnvironmentField () {
    linewithoutquotes=$( printf '%s\n' "$LINE" | tr -d '"' )
    b "$linewithoutquotes"
}
```

If you're using the `bash` shell, you may use its `${variable//pattern}` parameter substitution to delete double quotes,

```
updateEnvironmentField () {
    linewithoutquotes=${LINE//\"}
    b "$linewithoutquotes"
}
```

or just

```
updateEnvironmentField () {
    b "${LINE//\"}"
}
```

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)