# Cwebp -resize only if image is larger

Tags: image-manipulation, webp

cwebp - Compress an image file to a WebP file

`-resize width height`

Resize the source to a rectangle with size `width` x `height`. If either (but not both) of the width or height parameters is 0, the value will be calculated preserving the aspect-ratio.

The -resize option resizes the image to width but I want resize to occur only if image is larger than specified width x height.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are searching, use this snippet

*Note that it requires to install ImageMagick for getting image size*

```
#!/bin/bash

# On Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install imagemagick webp

for image in images/*.jpg; do
    if [[ ! -e $image ]];
        then continue;
    fi
    size=(`identify -format '%w %h' $image`)
    if [ ${size[0]} -gt ${size[1]} ]; then
        if [ ${size[0]} -gt 700 ]; then
            cwebp -q 50 -resize 700 0 -mt $image -o ${image%.*}.webp
        else
            cwebp -q 50 -mt $image -o ${image%.*}.webp
        fi
    else
        if [ ${size[1]} -gt 700 ]; then
            cwebp -q 50 -resize 0 700 -mt $image -o ${image%.*}.webp
        else
            cwebp -q 50 -mt $image -o ${image%.*}.webp
        fi
    fi
    rm $image
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. May I recommend, however, to make some modifications to the coding style: The shell variables should always be quoted unless you know exactly that you need word-splitting by the shell (particularly important when dealing with filenames). Also, the "backtick-style" for command substitutions is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated), and the new `$( ... )` style is now the recommended way of doing this.

Comment: @AdminBee Can you edit the answer or suggest the right style with '$(...)' and explain your meaning with shell variable quotes?