# How to restart ssh-agent without relogin

Tags: ssh-agent

I accidentally killed my `ssh-agent`, how do I restart it without having to reconnect ?

I tried this but it does not work :

```bsh
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 8055
```

Then, I open a new Gnome terminal with CTRL+SHIFT+N from the previous terminal window and type :

```bsh
$ ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

But if I open a new Gnome terminal from my first Gnome terminal by typing :

```bsh
$ gnome-terminal &
```

then this new window is able to connect to the `ssh-agent`.

Is it not possible for all my Gnome terminals to "see" the `ssh-agent` without having to reconnect to the PC/server ?

Answer (score 34):

**This doesn't work as you supposed. ssh-agent overwrites the configuration.**

TO FIX THIS---

*Find agent:*

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Agent pid 9546

*Kill PID:*

```
kill -9 9546
```

THEN YOU CHECK

```
ssh git@gitlab.com-test

ssh git@gitlab.com
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 5):

```
killall ssh-agent; eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind adding some explanation on how that solves the OPs problem? Also, please note that the "backtick" notation for command substitutions is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated), and the `$( ... )` syntax is recommended instead.

Comment: I have my doubts that this would "restart (ssh-agent) without having to reconnect"; perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: I just tested this on MacOS. It works the same way the accepted answer works, but is simpler. I'd suggest `ssh-agent -k` rather than `killall ssh-agent` though — no need to potentially kill more processes than we need to.

Answer (score 0):

Try restart using the following command:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

The private/public RSA SSH keys are located in ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, respectively. You can transfer the public key to another machine to connect to it through public key authentication. This can be done via ssh-copy-id like so:

```
ssh-copy-id username@host
```

Or you can append your public key (id_rsa.pub) to the server's /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys file, which is in essence what ssh-copy-id does.

Comment: This command does not restart the `ssh-agent`, it only restarts the `ssh` service

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your original `ssh-agent` was probably started by your GUI session start-up scripts, and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable created at that point was inherited by the processes of your desktop environment.

Any new processes started through the GUI will keep inheriting the old value, and any running Gnome terminal processes (and the shells inside them) have already inherited the old value. You would need to push the new `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value into every process that has the old value, and also trigger every running `ssh` client process to reconfigure themselves to use the new value. There is simply no mechanism for this.

What you could do instead, is note the old and new `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` values, and then **create a symbolic link in place of the old agent socket, pointing to the new socket**.

In other words:

```
ln -sf <new SSH_AUTH_SOCK value> <old SSH_AUTH_SOCK value>
```

Just remember that the new agent is still a child process of the shell it was started from, and may die if that shell exits.