# Environment variables don't expand correctly when related to a function

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Here is a part of my `.bashrc` file:

```
echo_pwd () {
    echo `pwd`
}
export echo_pwd="`echo_pwd`/"
```

I created a new function `echo_pwd` that prints the path of the current directory and a new environment variable that contains the current directory followed by a slash. Therefore, I can use my environment variable in command line (such as `$PWD`).

However, this environment variable doesn't expand correctly and always refers to my home directory:

```
~/Documents$ env | grep echo_pwd
echo_pwd=/home/pierre/
~/Documents$
```

What can I do to make my environment variable expands correctly?

*Note: this is obviously a dummy example. In my specific use case, the `echo_pwd` is a much more complex function.*

Comment: Side issue: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: I can't recreate what you're seeing. When I execute your function in a non-`$HOME` directory, the correct directory path is assigned to the variable `echo_pwd`. Are you not re-executing it when changing directories?  Also, why don't you use `$PWD`?

Comment: @Kusalananda As i said in my note at the end of the question, my function is much more complex and I simplify it for the question.
Whatever, your comment helps me to understand where the issue is. The environment variable is set only when I open the terminal. If I open it in my home directory, even if I change the directory with `cd`, `$echo_pwd` will always be `/home/pierre`.
Therefore, is there a way to have an environment variable (or something else) that can change dynamically?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Indeed, if I use this syntax `$(echo_pwd)`, I don't have to create an environment variable and its value is always updated when  I change of directory.

Comment: I think you expect the variable to update its value automatically based on the changing output of the function. That won't happen.

Comment: I am wondering why an environment variable, and not just a variable?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If you know how to do it with a simple variable, I'm interested too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely only executing the function and setting your variable's value once.

To automatically update the variable's value whenever you use `cd`, you may override the shell's built-in `cd` like so:

```bash
cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"
    echo_pwd=$( echo_pwd )/
}
```

This would call the built-in `cd` with whatever arguments you gave the `cd` function, and then update tha value of your variable (note that `export` is not needed if you have already exported it elsewhere, if it needs to be exported at all).

The complete setup could look like

```
echo_pwd () {
    printf '%s\n' "$PWD"    # or just: pwd
}
export echo_pwd="$( echo_pwd )/"

cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"
    echo_pwd=$( echo_pwd )/
}
```

I've opted for [using `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) with `$PWD` instead of calling the `pwd` utility, and I'm also [using `$(...)` for command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927).

Answer (score 1):

In `` export echo_pwd="`echo_pwd`/" ``, the command substitution is performed only once, when the variable is set.

If you need to update the value of the variable, you'd need to set it again.

In interactive bash, you could use [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt), which is executed each time the prompt is printed:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo_pwd="`echo_pwd`/"'
$ cd bar/
$ echo $echo_pwd/
/tmp/foo/bar//
$ cd baz
$ echo $echo_pwd
/tmp/foo/bar/baz/
```