# How can I extract part of the output of a curl command and assign it to a shell variable - part 2?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, regular-expression, curl

```
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 188 100 188 0 0 180 0 0:00:01 0:00:01 --:--:--
180{"result":{"fileId":"3a29ca7a-813a-4b3b-9b9c-
6f9251d2171d","percentComplete":100.0,"status":"complete"},"meta":{"requestId":"*************************************************************************","httpStatus":"200 - OK"}}
```

Again - I need to extract the highlighted part that follows "fileId":

I tried using the following -

```
VAR2="$(curl <...> | sed -E -n 's/.*fileId":"([^"]+).+/\2/p')"
```

But when I run echo $VAR2 I do not get any output

p.s. ideally I want this to happen only when percentComplete:100.0 (but this is not a priority, extracting the fileId is the priority for now)

Comment: Is that output one line or many? Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your question, and make sure you format the output as code.

Comment: Stéphane's answer to your other question could easily be extended to cover this case: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586809/116858

Comment: I tried using the solution Stephanie provided - did not work for me

Comment: @VirajDeshpande In what specific way did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
VAR2="$(curl<..> | sed -E -n 's/.*fileId":"([^"]+).+/\1/p')"
```

The problem with your try is that you used `\2` in the `sed` command, but you only have one regex group. I think you should take a look at the `sed` [info page](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to understand how `sed` works.

Comment: Or even better, parse the JSON with a JSON parser...