# how to display all directories listed in $PATH

Tags: path

How to display all directories listed in the `$PATH`?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/q/600018

Comment: Display the directories, or display the _contents_ of the directories?

Answer (score 3):

```
printf '%s' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
```

Used the `tr` command, because a *HINT* in the [original version of the question](/revisions/589727/1) suggested using it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `bash` (and also assuming that you know how to show the value of shell variables with `echo` or `printf`)

```
printf "${PATH//:/\\n}"
```

This makes use of parameter expansion within the shell. The expansion as such is `${parameter/pattern/string}` with `PATH` as the parameter, `/:` as the pattern and `\\n` as the (replacement) string. The leading `/` in the pattern indicates that the replacement should be done on all occurrences of `:` within `PATH`.

Comment: Leaving that expansion unquoted doesn't make any sense. That would also not work properly if `$PATH` contains backslash or `%` characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean list their contents, then in a POSIX shell, you can do:

```
(IFS=:; set -o noglob; ls -Hl -- $PATH)
```

That assumes `$PATH` has no empty (for current directory) components.

With the `fish` shell, that would just be:

```
ls -Hl -- $PATH
```

(`fish` converts the `PATH` environment variable into a shell array variable where empty components are changed to `.`).

With `(t)csh`:

```
ls -Hl -- $path:q
```

(`$PATH` is *mapped* to the `$path` array there, and empty strings converted to `.`).

In `zsh`, `$PATH` is mapped to a `$path` array as well, but empty components not changed to `.`, so you'd need something like:

```
ls -Hl -- "${path[@]/#%/.}"
```

To do the conversion by hand.

If all you want is output those paths one per line as opposed to list the contents of the corresponding directories, then just replace `ls -Hl --` with `printf '%s\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

Edit: If you wanna show contents

```
ls `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'`
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, though, that the backtick-notation for command substitutions is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) and the new `"$( ... )"`-style is recommended.