# best way to fetch the exit code from the redirection document script

Tags: linux, rhel, exit-status

```
if [ ! -z "admin_us" ]
then
newgrp admin_us<< END
 command=` abc.sh `
END
fi
echo $?
```

What we have seen here is, the exit code is always 0, even if the **abc.sh** fails, what is a better way to fetch the exit code?
The last option for me is to save it in a temporary file and read it outside.

Comment: I would say that the exit status is from the `newgrp` command, not `abc.sh`. The question is, when is your code supposed to fail? When `newgrp` fails, or `abc.sh`, or both? It's not clear to me, by the way, why you provide input to `newgrp`. When you run `newgrp admin_us`, it simply ignores any input.

Comment: @berndbausch - I need it from the abc.sh , if newgrp fail , then I will anyways get the exit code

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: @cas - `Bash`  it is

Comment: Run `abc.sh`, assign its exit code to a variable e.g. `abc` and its output to another variable e.g. `output`. Use `$output` to perform whatever you want with `newgrp`, then exit with `exit $abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heredoc script needs to exit with $? as the exit code.

e.g. minimum-working example (that assumes my UID is a member of `users` and doesn't require your `abc.sh` script (uses `false` instead)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ 1 == 1 ]; then
newgrp users << END
 command=$(false)
 exit $?
END
fi
echo $?
```

NOTE: `newgrp` forks a new shell, and can't change the value of `$command` in its parent.  You probably want something more like:

```
if [ ! -z "admin_us" ]; then
  command=$(newgrp admin_us <<<'abc.sh')
fi
echo "$?"
echo "$command"
```

BTW, don't use backticks.  Use `$(...)` instead.  backticks are deprecated, only retained for backwards-compatibility with older shells/scripts. See [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)

Comment: thanks it worked