# Compact way to generate variable with 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

A `bash` script is using a variable `Q` for some purpose (outside the scope of this question):

```
Q=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

As this script is used in an environment where each byte counts, this is waste. But some workaround like

```
Q=0$(seq -s "" 9)$(echo {A..Z}|tr -d " ")
```

(for `C` locale) is even worse. Am I too blind to see the obvious trick to compactly generate such a simple sequence?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: That's all of 39 bytes, including the newline. Is that really a problem? On a system that's capable of running a POSIX-compatible or POSIX-like shell??

Comment: @ilkkachu The script can be part of packets transferred over a poor network.

Comment: ok, fair. Would it be possible to preload that snippet on the systems that need it? Then you could do just `. a` to load it. Or even better, set it as an environment variable somewhere where it then becomes available to the script.

Comment: @ilkkachu That would be preferred, if I could control that system.

Comment: ah, indeed. My condolences.

Comment: @ilkkachu My own fault. I can release an update, but those packets need to be compatible with legacy systems, probably forever. I should have thought of this before the first release, but `Q` was introduced later. *sigh*

Comment: If you have some standard tools available on the receiving end, maybe you could compress the script before sending it, un-compressing it on the other end before running? It is possible to create a bash script that decompresses itself when run; for a short script the overhead involved wouldn't pay off, but if every byte counts there is some number of bytes where it may be worth it, if possible.

Comment: This is definitely in the domain of micro-optimisations. Before starting to address things like this, I hope you've spent a whole lot of time trying to get rid of every larger-scale structural inefficiencies (which may include things like, if applicable, compressing it before sending it, sending it less often or making network or low-level message configuration changes).

Comment: What character encoding is in use?  Because you've written `{A..Z}`, I'm guessing it's one in which the letters are contiguous, but the question would be better if you made that explicit.

Comment: Sometimes the reason for wishing such compactness is not about saving system resources. It could be a case of something that must go across an air gap (has to be read and typed in by hand), or for recovery of a system where only console access without copy paste is possible, or ... exploit code for whatever-hat purposes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For any shell capable of brace expansion:

Using `printf`:

```
$ printf %s {0..9} {A..Z}
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

-->

```
Q=$(printf %s {0..9} {A..Z})
```

Backticks instead of `$()` saves one byte. For Bash specifically, `printf -v var` to printf into a variable is nice but no shorter than backticks.

```
printf -vQ %s {0..9} {A..Z}
Q=`printf %s {0..9} {A..Z}`
```

Comment: `printf` can print to variables directly without a subshell by using the -v option: `printf -v Q %s {0..9} {A..Z}`

Comment: Use backticks to save 1 byte.

Comment: @annahri That's [bad advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/3645).

Comment: @l0b0: Not really. It's not like backticks are going away; there certainly _are_ downsides to backticks (e.g. less readable, some restrictions on complex commands) - but for this specific case, in an environment where you're trying to save every byte, it's a perfectly reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: @annahri you can use perl and save another **3** bytes: `Q=\`perl -Esay+0..9,A..Z\`` . Just kidding. The idea that you would "save" anything by replacing a simple string with a command substitution (forking another process, setting up its i/o, and all the heavy lifting that it entails) it totally ludicrous. I guess that the only point of this "question" was to gather views and rep points.

Comment: @UncleBilly I strongly believe that this question is for code golfing.

Comment: @annahri Eventually, this answer did make it into a real world system. No hobby golfing.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way I know is to use `bash` way:

```
echo {0..9} {A..Z}|sed 's/ //g'
```

(`sed` is used to remove space between symbols. Space between brackets is important otherwise you will see all combination from 0 to 9 and A to Z like `0A0B0C0D0E0F0G0H0I0J0K0L0M0N0O0P0Q0R0S0T0U0V0W0X0Y0Z1A1B1C...`)

By suggest you can shorter the command like this:

```
echo {0..9} {A..Z}|tr -d ' '
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with my `busybox`. My `tr -d " "` is a little shorter than your `sed 's/ //g'`, so I can change to `Q=$(echo {0..9} {A..Z}|tr -d " ")`. Your answer is really a progress, but no match for the `printf` solution.

Comment: @ilkkachu `BusyBox v1.30.1`, but – oops! – I just see that `ash` symlinks to `busybox`, but `sh` symlinks to `bash.bash`, which is a `bash 4.4.23`. So excuses: My question had a mistake.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, that's pretty much part of what I was saying. If Solaris has (had) as `sh` something they call "Bourne Shell", but with csh or ksh features, it just makes it harder to know what people actually mean when they say "Bourne Shell". (On top of all the people who just call Bash or POSIX sh, or POSIX-like shells "Bourne", without specifying it any further, that is.)

Comment: If you're playing golf, replace `tr -d " "` with `tr -d \ ` (one trailing space) and save a character at the expense of readability

Comment: For the record, even with @roaima's suggestion, Q=\`echo {0..9} {A..Z}|tr -d \ \` is 4 bytes longer than an optimal `printf` capture or `-vQ`.  I tried but `tr` won't accept the char to delete as part of the same argument, so `tr -d\ ` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Frame challenge: **don't**.

Any way you could do this will be at best more resource-intensive than just writing what you already wrote, and the more efficient ways are also less portable (forcing you to write a "Bash script" rather than a "shell script").

In general, regardless of language, the optimal form for constant tables is a literal constant table, not something generated programmatically at runtime. If it's large enough that hard-coding it would be error-prone, generate it programmatically while writing the program or during "build time" for the program, and include the output as a literal constant in your actual program.

Comment: Writing stuff like that manually can be more error prone (ie, missing or repeating a letter).

Comment: @Shadow: My answer addresses that. "If it's large enough that hard-coding it would be error-prone..."

Comment: It doesn't have to be large for that to be a possible concern.

Comment: The threshold is subject to your judgement.

Comment: @Shadow - putting the literal into the script doesn't mean that it needs to be typed manually. You could use the technique in other answers to generate it and then paste it in

Comment: @MartinSmith: Which is exactly what I advocated in the third paragraph of this answer. :-)

Answer (score -4):

Again, **don't**, but if you really must, a pattern that generalizes decently without needing special shell features is:

```
printf %b $(printf \\x%.2x $(seq 48 57) $(seq 65 90))
```

The `seq` utility can be written as a shell function if you don't want to depend on it.

Comment: How was this nominated for deletion??

Comment: It's not a shell feature - it's a separate program. If you don't want to depend on it, it can be written as a shell function.

Comment: True, I made a mistake there. My point is: You mention portability and resource intensiveness in your other answer, but Seq is not part of POSIX either and this answers spawns a couple of processes. I don't see advantage in it.

Comment: The value of the answer is the pattern for generating strings from sequences of numeric character codes, which doesn't inherently involve seq just printf.