# How do I find directories with a given name and move their contents up one level?

Tags: bash, find

I know how to find all directories with a given name:

```
find . -name unnecessary_dir_level
```

and how to move files to a parent dir:

```
mv * ..
```

how do I combine things - is

```
find . -name unnecessary_dir_level -exec mv {}/* {}/.. \;
```

going to do the job without causing chaos? or what will? I'm not keen on trying this without advice (and the directories are too big to back up in a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: What's the plan for name collisions? I.e., what are you planning to do when there is a file called `myfile` both in the directory that you want to move the contents from, and in the directory that you want to move the contents _to_.  Also "too big to back up" is something I've never seen so far, ever.

Comment: re. collision: ```mv -u```, plus the parent folder only contains the folder to be moved from - that's why it's unnecessary; re too big - yes, you're right. the full sentence is "too big for the space I've got left on the device and the time it would take to transfer it over the network".

Comment: Like many tasks, this is an exercise in iteration.  First, you need to craft a script (perhaps a `bash` function) that can correctly process **one** such directory, given the path to that directory. Once you have a solid procedure for how to process one directory, you can then simply call that function N more times, once for each of the N remaining directories.  Don't worry about how to do something 1,000 times; instead, solve the question of how to do it once.  Then repeat that as many times as needed.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` and a `mv` implementation with support for a `-n` (no clobber)  option, you could do:

```
for dir (**/unnecessary_dir_level(ND/od)) () {
  (( ! $# )) || mv -n -- $@ $dir:h/ && rmdir -- $dir
} $dir/*(ND)
```

Where:

- `for var (values) cmd` is the short (and more familiar among programming languages) version of the `for` loop.
- `**/`: a glob operator that means *any level of subdirectories*
- `N` glob qualifier: enables `nullglob` for that glob (don't complain if there's no match)
- `D` glob qualifier: enables `dotglob` for that glob (include hidden files)
- `/` glob qualifier: restrict to files of type *directory*.
- `od` glob qualifier: `o`rder by `d`epth (leaves before the branch they're on)
- `() { body; } args`: anonymous function with its args.
- here *args* being `$dir/*(ND)`: all the files including hidden ones in `$dir`
- the *body* running `mv` on those files if there are any and then `rmdir` on the `$dir` that should now be empty.
- `$dir:h`, the `h`ead of `$dir` (its dirname, like in csh).

Note that `mv * ..` is wrong on two accounts:

- it's missing the option delimiter: `mv -- * ..`
- you're missing the hidden files: `mv -- *(D) ..` in zsh, (`(shopt -s nullglob failglob; exec mv -- * ..)` in `bash`)
- also: you could end up losing data if there's a file with the same name in the parent.

```
find . -name unnecessary_dir_level -exec mv {}/* {}/.. \;
```

Can't work as the `{}/*` glob is expanded by the shell before calling `mv`. It would only  be expanded to something if there was a directory called `{}` in the current directory, and then move the wrong files.

---

You could do something similar with `find` and `bash` with:

```
find . -depth -name unnecessary_dir_level -type d -exec \
  bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -c '
    for dir do
      set -- "$dir"/*
      (( ! $# )) || mv -n -- "$@" "${dir%/*}" && rmdir -- "$dir"
    done' bash {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` version >= 4.0:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for f in **/name/; do echo mv "$f"* "$f"..; done
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`: If  set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

> `nullglob`: If  set,  bash allows patterns which match no files [...] to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

> `dotglob`: If  set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of pathname expansion.

Comment: You need bash 5.0 or newer for `**/` to work *properly* in 4.x, `**/name` would also find the `name`s that are in directories pointed to by symlinks in the current directory.

Comment: In any case, even with 5+, `**/name/` will include the symlinks called `name` that point to a file of type directory. You'd need to exclude them with  `[ -L "${f%/}" ] && continue`...

Comment: You'd also need to process the list depth-first. For instance, if you have a `a/name/b/name` dir if you move `a/name/b` to `a/b`, then when it comes to process `a/name/b/name`, it will no longer be there. Reversing the expansion of the `**/name/` glob would do it, but it's painful to do in `bash`, so you might as well use `find` that fixes all those problems as in the approach in my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for loop` to move each found directory's content one level above. For example, I have `temp` file in `abc` directory.

```
tmp/abc/
└── temp
```

The following command will put `temp` in `tmp` directory:

```
for i in ` find . -name abc ` ; do mv $i/* $i/.. ; done
```

Comment: This will break if the file (or directory) has whitespace or newlines in the filename.

Comment: You may want to read [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: You might also consider using the `$(...)` syntax instead of backticks. Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) for instance on the change.