# fish shell: why does `file `which command`` work in zsh and bash, but not fish?

Tags: command-substitution, fish

Before switching to fish shell, I frequently used various commands in `zsh` with `which some_command`. An example might be:

```
$ file `which zsh`
/opt/local/bin/zsh: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
/bin/zsh:           Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
- Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
- Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/bin/zsh (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/bin/zsh (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

When I try to do this with `fish` it fails:

```
$ which zsh
/opt/local/bin/zsh

$ file `which zsh`
`which: cannot open ``which' (No such file or directory)
zsh`:   cannot open `zsh`' (No such file or directory)
```

Any idea of why this doesn't work `fish` as opposed to other more bash-like shells?

Comment: In general, even in Bash, Zsh, POSIX sh, etc., the use of backticks is strongly discouraged.  See the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03), *"Because of these inconsistent behaviors, the backquoted variety of command substitution is not recommended for new applications that nest command substitutions or attempt to embed complex scripts.*"  Reference [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/432493).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fish does not use backticks for command substitutions. Instead one can use parens: `file (which zsh)` or (in release 3.4.0 and later) `file $(which zsh)`. These mean the same thing.

Check out [fish for bash users](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html) for other differences.

Comment: Too bad it's not a little more terse/abbreviated regardless of the POSIX standard. <sigh> Wonder if there's a way to hack in an abbreviation of sorts?

Comment: @ylluminate I'm not sure how you can get any more terse/abbreviated than `(command)`.  It's the same number of characters as using backticks, just (much) less error-prone when nesting.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in `zsh`, you'd rather use:

```
file -- =zsh
```

Or:

```
() {file -- $1:c} zsh
```

`file $(which zsh)` (the modern version of the deprecated `` file `which zsh` ``) would only work if there was no alias or function also defined for `zsh` and if the path to the zsh command didn't start with `-` nor end in newline characters¹ and didn't contain characters of `$IFS` (space, tab, newline and nul by default).

```
file -- "$(whence -p zsh)"
```

Would be more correct (`which` in `zsh` being an alias for `whence -c`, `-c` for `csh`, `which` being originally a csh script for csh users).

In `fish`, as [`fish`'s maintainer already said](/a/704535), command substitution is with `(...)` or also `$(...)` in recent versions (the latter can be used inside double quotes).

Contrary to `zsh`, `fish` doesn't have `which` builtin, so the behaviour will vary with the system you're on, [`which` being a non-standard, often broken command](/q/85249).

`fish` has a `type` builtin command though which supports a `-P` option to force a `$PATH` lookup like zsh's `whence -p`.

By default command substitutions are split on newline characters. If using `$(...)` inside double quotes however, there's no splitting but all the trailing newline characters are removed.

So with `fish`, a more correct version would be:

```
file -- "$(type -P zsh)"
```

or with older versions:

```
file -- (type -P zsh | string collect)
```

(with one difference from the `"$(...)"` in that if `type` produces no output (or only newlines) it will not pass any argument to `file` instead of one empty argument).

---

<sup>¹ for `which zsh` to return something ending in newline, you'd need to have done `hash zsh=$'/path/to/some/fileendinginnewline\n\n'` for instance though, which is quite contrived here.</sup>

Comment: `string collect --allow-empty` was added in fish 3.4.0, same as `$()`. It will work in the exact same versions.

Comment: Also @ridiculous_fish is not fish's "original author", the original author has left the project. He is the maintainer, tho.

Comment: Thanks @faho. Both should be fixed now.