How to print a Windows relative path from a Windows .lnk file as a Linux relative path?
Let's assume that on a Windows NTFS partition we have an .lnk file pointing to some other file:
$ lnkinfo invoice.lnk | grep "Relative path"
        Relative path                   : ..\..\dir1\dir2\invoice.pdf

Is there a command, say, lnk_to_linpath, that extracts and converts such a Windows relative path to a Linux relative path? The goal is that, in our example,
$ evince `lnk_to_linpath invoice.lnk` &

opens the linked invoice PDF. (If the new path doesn't seem to exist, lnk_to_linpath should behave reasonably, say, ignore or send an error message to stderr and return a nonzero code.) The task seems so common (related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762102/how-do-i-open-windows-shortcuts-lnk-files) that someone might have done the job, and we don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Looks like you can just use what you have there. You can get the relative path with (untested since I have neither lnkinfo nor Windows on my system):
lnkinfo invoice.lnk | grep -oP 'Relative path\s*:\s*\K.*'

The -o flag tells grep to only print the matching portion of the line, and the -P enables PCRE (perl compatible regular expressions) which give us \s (whitespace characters) and \K (forget anything matched before this). So the regex looks for Relative path, 0 or more whitespace characters (\s*), then a : and 0 or more whitespace characters again. Then, then \K makes grep discard anything matched so far, so it will only print the rest of the line, the path.
Based on the input you show, that should return ..\..\dir1\dir2\invoice.pdf. So we're half way there, we just need to change \ for / which we can do with tr '\\' '/'.
Putting all this together, we can write a little function:
lnk_to_linpath(){
   lnkinfo "$1" | grep -oP 'Relative path\s*:\s*\K.*' | tr '\\' '/'
}

Add those lines to your ~/.bashrc (or equivalent, if not using bash), open a new terminal and you can now do
evince `lnk_to_linpath invoice.lnk` &

Or, better since backticks are deprecated:
evince "$(lnk_to_linpath invoice.lnk)" &


Does this also work if there are spaces somewhere inside in the Windows relative path?

@AlMa1r yes, as long as you use evince "$(lnk_to_linpath invoice.lnk)" & and not evince `lnk_to_linpath invoice.lnk` &

Thank you! +1!!!

An aside. I now learned that though the use of backticks (\``) is discouraged in favor of the newer $(...)` syntax, they are not fully deprecated in Bash: they are not going to be removed any time soon. Cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928 on terminology.

@AlMa1r yes, exactly. They are deprecated, not removed. Too many old scripts still use them, but we shouldn't be writing new ones.

Yes, I agree, and I used them on the command line quite often: besides being used to the backticks, I like it that they take up less screen space. My stuff is mostly not publicly available, so I may do whatever I wish :-).
